# ES6 modules implementation, how to load a json file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack

I'm implementing an example from  https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest

Important code is like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import suburbs from 'json!../suburbs.json';

function getSuggestions(input, callback) {
  const suggestions = suburbs
    .filter(suburbObj => suburbMatchRegex.test(suburbObj.suburb))
    .sort((suburbObj1, suburbObj2) =>
      suburbObj1.suburb.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercasedInput) -
      suburbObj2.suburb.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercasedInput)
    )
    .slice(0, 7)
    .map(suburbObj => suburbObj.suburb);

  // 'suggestions' will be an array of strings, e.g.:
  //   ['Mentone', 'Mill Park', 'Mordialloc']

  setTimeout(() => callback(null, suggestions), 300);
}
```

This copy-paste code from the example (that works), has an error in my project:

```
Error: Cannot resolve module 'json' in /home/juanda/redux-pruebas/components
```

If I take out the prefix json!:

```
import suburbs from '../suburbs.json';
```

This way I got not errors at compile time (import is done).
However I got errors when I execute it:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _jsonfilesSuburbsJson2.default.filter is not a function
```

If I debug it I can see suburbs is an objectc, not an array so filter function is not defined.

However in the example is commented suggestions is an array. If I rewrite suggestions like this, everything works:

```
  const suggestions = suburbs
  var suggestions = [ {
    'suburb': 'Abbeyard',
    'postcode': '3737'
  }, {
    'suburb': 'Abbotsford',
    'postcode': '3067'
  }, {
    'suburb': 'Aberfeldie',
    'postcode': '3040'
  } ].filter(suburbObj => suburbMatchRegex.test(suburbObj.suburb))
```

So... what json! prefix is doing in the import?

Why can't I put it in my code? Some babel configuration?

Comment: Please, please, please re-evaluate the chose answer this is actually want you're using ES6 modules. You don't need anything at all, just a JS that understands ES6 modules.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53878451/124486

Answer (score 167, accepted):

First of all you need to install [`json-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader):

```
npm i json-loader --save-dev
```

Then, there are two ways how you can use it:

1. In order to avoid adding [`json-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader) in each `import` you can add to `webpack.config` this line:

   ```
   loaders: [
     { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
     // other loaders 
   ]
   ```

   Then import `json` files like this

   ```
   import suburbs from '../suburbs.json';
   ```
2. Use [`json-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader) directly in your `import`, as in your example:

   ```
   import suburbs from 'json!../suburbs.json';
   ```

**Note:** 
In **`webpack 2.*`** instead of keyword `loaders` need to use [**`rules`**](https://webpack.js.org/how-to/upgrade-from-webpack-1/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules).,

also **`webpack 2.*`** uses `json-loader` by default

> *.json files are now supported without the json-loader. You may still use it. It's not a breaking change.
>
> [`v2.1.0-beta.28`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta.28)

Comment: Thank you so much! The documentation for json-loader was actually showing the settings for webpack v2, so nothing worked for me (using v1!). So for all of you out there, use loaders, not rules! Plus, change 'use' inside that object to be 'loader', just like this answer!

Comment: As @alexander-t mentioned, you can now import json files without the json-loader, but, if you run into an issue where the json-loader is not recognized, you should just add a '-loader' suffix in the loaders config like this: `{ test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }`

Comment: Why doesn't the imported json get copied into outDir if it's being imported via typescript?

Comment: What if you don't have a `webpack.config`?

Answer (score 20):

json-loader doesn't load json file if it's array, in this case you need to make sure it has a key, for example

```
{
    "items": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues/598",
      "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet",
      "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues/598/labels{/name}",
      "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues/598/comments",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues/598/events",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/issues/598",
      "id": 199425790,
      "number": 598,
      "title": "Just a heads up (LINE SEPARATOR character issue)",
    },
    ..... other items in array .....
]}
```

Comment: Nice one, didn't thought about that !

Comment: how is this an answer??? if it doesnt load this particular json file, then what is way to load such json file???

Answer (score 10):

This just works on React & React Native

```
const data = require('./data/photos.json');

console.log('[-- typeof data --]', typeof data); // object


const fotos = data.xs.map(item => {
    return { uri: item };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

With [`json-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader) installed, now you can simply use:

```
import suburbs from '../suburbs.json';
```

or, even more simply:

```
import suburbs from '../suburbs';
```

Answer (score 2):

## Node v8.5.0+

You don't need JSON loader. Node provides [ECMAScript Modules (ES6 Module support)](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) with the `--experimental-modules` flag, you can use it like this

```
node --experimental-modules myfile.mjs
```

Then it's very simple

```
import myJSON from './myJsonFile.json';
console.log(myJSON);
```

Then you'll have it bound to the variable `myJSON`.

Comment: What about using this?
`import * as myJSON from './myJsonFile.json';`

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread when I couldn't load a `json-file` with `ES6 TypeScript 2.6`. I kept getting this error:

> TS2307 (TS) Cannot find module 'json-loader!./suburbs.json'

To get it working I had to declare the module first. I hope this will save a few hours for someone.

```
declare module "json-loader!*" {
  let json: any;
  export default json;
}

...

import suburbs from 'json-loader!./suburbs.json';
```

If I tried to omit `loader` from `json-loader` I got the following error from `webpack`:

> BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix
>   when using loaders.
>                    You need to specify 'json-loader' instead of 'json',
>                    see https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed