# Include .json file in .js module

Tags: ember-cli

I have a translations file at:

```
frontend/locales/en/translations.js
```

which looks like:

```
export default {
  back: "Back",
  or: "Or",
  cancel: "Cancel",
};
```

I want to move the translations hash into a .json file:

```
frontend/locales/en/translations.json
```

and somehow include it in the .js file.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: So, this is for Node, or what environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a pretty slick solution:  [ember-cli-json-module](https://github.com/IvyApp/ember-cli-json-module).

After installing this add-on, I can do:

```
// master.json:
{
  "back": "Back",
  "or": "Or",
  "cancel": "Cancel"
}

// translations.js:
import masterFile from './master';

export default masterFile;
```

I also removed the EcmaScript6 tag, as this is a specifically ember-cli solution.

Answer (score 0):

`EcmaScript 6 modules` don't allow to import `.json` (or something else), they are focused on javascript only.

this is a reference: [How to import a json file in ecmascript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6)

You can do it using some bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) that has a specific [`json-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader).

If you don't use any bundler, consider to use javascript instead of JSON, because JSON is a `Javascript Object Notation`, the only difference is that JSON is simple string (that you can parse).

So use javascript directly without any `JSON.parse`.

If you need to use `json formats` you can load them via Javascript...

Have a look at https://blog.gospodarets.com/fetch_in_action
`fetch('/path/to/locale/en.json).then(res => res.json()).then(translations => console.log('translations', translations));`

Comment: *"EcmaScript 6 modules don't allow to import .json (or something else), they are focused on javascript only."* Ultimately it's the module loader that does or does not support loading of non-JavaScript files. ES6 modules only provide a specification for syntax and (some) semantics. How module identifiers are resolved depends on the environment. E.g. `import Foo from './bar.json'` in Node (given, of course, that you transpile `import` to `require`), because Node allows to load JSON files.