# How can I parse through local JSON file in React js?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

How can I parse through a JSON file retrieving all its data and using it in my code?

I've tried importing the file and just tried console logging it, but all it does is print Object {}:

```
import jsonData from "./file.json";
console.log(jsonData);
```

This is what my file.json looks like:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "gender": "Female",
      "first_name": "Helen",
      "last_name": "Nguyen",
      "email": "hnguyen0@bloomberg.com",
      "ip_address": "227.211.25.18"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "gender": "Male",
      "first_name": "Carlos",
      "last_name": "Fowler",
      "email": "cfowler1@gnu.org",
      "ip_address": "214.248.201.11"
    }
]
```

I'd want to be able to access the first and last name of each component and print those on the website.

Comment: this seemed to work for me as is

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
var data = require('../../file.json'); // forward slashes will depend on the file location
```

```js
var data = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "gender": "Female",
      "first_name": "Helen",
      "last_name": "Nguyen",
      "email": "hnguyen0@bloomberg.com",
      "ip_address": "227.211.25.18"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "gender": "Male",
      "first_name": "Carlos",
      "last_name": "Fowler",
      "email": "cfowler1@gnu.org",
      "ip_address": "214.248.201.11"
    }
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    var obj = data[i];
    console.log(`Name: ${obj.last_name}, ${obj.first_name}`);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c9wupvo6/

Comment: I am getting this error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "json!./Sections/file.json"` even though that is the right path.

Answer (score 19):

Applications packaged with webpack 2.0.0+ (such as those created with [create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app)) support imports from json exactly as in the question (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34946395/1057157).

Be aware that `import` caches the result, even if that result is parsed json, so if you modify that object, other modules that also import it have references to the **same object**, not a newly parsed copy.

To get a "clean" copy, you can make a function that clones it such as:

```
import jsonData from './file.json';

const loadData = () => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

Or if you're using [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash):

```
import jsonData from './file.json';
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash';

const loadData = () => cloneDeep(jsonData);
```

Comment: you need to put that json file inside src folder.

Answer (score 17):

I also had problems with getting an empty Object back. Even when using `require` as suggested above.

`fetch` however solved my problem:

```
fetch('./data/fakeData.json')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('data:', data);
  })
```

(As of today, the support isn't optimal though: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch)

Comment: This seems like it should work. But whenever I try it I get "localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: how to make this work? the url generated for the fetch is incorrect. hence the jseals. error.

Comment: @Community I've found a solution! Instead of passing the relative path, you need to pass the complete path(inside your project), like `fetch("src/data/fakeData.json)`. Instead of using `res.json()`, use `res.text()`, and, in the last then, use `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Thanks Muchachito - its getting there  - just DONT FORGET to wrap this inside a useEffect or it wont work & also loop forever while failing

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who also have trouble with this, this code seemed to have fixed the problem

```
var jsonData = require('../../file.json');

class blah extends React.Component {

render(){
    var data; 

    function loadJSON(jsonfile, callback) {   

        var jsonObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        jsonObj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        jsonObj.open('GET', "../../file.json", true);
        jsonObj.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (jsonObj.readyState == 4 && jsonObj.status == "200") {
                callback(jsonObj.responseText);
              }
        };
        jsonObj.send(null);  
     }

    function load() {

        loadJSON(jsonData, function(response) {
            data = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    load();
}

}
```

Comment: This seems excessive for getting JSON into a local JS code, isn't there an easier solution?

Answer (score 2):

The JS spread operator also helps to get a deep copy of the object.

```
import jsonData from '../../file.json';

const loadData = [...jsonData];
```

Comment: The spread operator is a SHALLOW copy, not a deep one. The above would result in a new array, but the exact same object instances within it.

Comment: @EricHaynes is right