# Using fetch and ES6 to load local JSON files

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, es6-promise

**Introduction**

I have a local file `'countryballs.json'` which I want to **load it on a html and parse the data** into the `index.html`.

The way I want to do it, and the only one I know, it's by using [Fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch). Quite easy to use.

**Code**

```
async function getData()
        {
            await fetch('./countryballs.json')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
        getData();
```

**Code explanation**

Fetch should be used in a async function as it returns a promise *(loading files takes time)*

await fetch() //Will wait until all has being loaded. The rest of the code is self-explanatory ES6 JS coding.

**Problem**

When working with external API's (for weather, finance and stuff) it just works perfectly, I can retrieve and parse the data and everything goes well. Even loading local CVS files. **But not with my local JSON file.**

**ERROR**

```
index.html:15 GET http://localhost:8080/countryballs.json 404 (Not Found)
```

XMLHttprequest log:

```
index.html:15 Fetch failed loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/countryballs.json".
```

**Questions**

- Why it does not work with JSON files too?
- What I am missing in the code?

**Example .json**

```
[
  {
    "country": [
      {
        "name": "Spain",
        "GDP": " $1234",
        "Regions": " Europe ",
        "Align": " Western "
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**People with similar problems but different solutions or it didn't worked for me**

- [Loading local JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)
- [Fetching local JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481934/fetching-local-json)

**Further explanation to understand the problem**

- The folder where I am working looks like this:

  - node-modules
  - index.html
  - countryballs.json
- I am using Node.js and Visual Studio Code
- The index.html runs on a localhost:8080 using Chrome Browser

**Possible solution that I considered**

- Using the File System to load it *(but still want to try fetch())*

**Image gallery of the problem**

*(Chrome's console output)*

[image: Hope you help me find a solution]

**Edit:**

As some of you requested I will provide what I have here and below the instructions to test.

[GoogleDrive file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-QuVFF4Gf_WzRbnbZ7e-dVZikT016bQP/view?usp=sharing)

```
1. Get node.js
2. cd into the folder with the index.html and the rest
3. call for `node http-server`
4. get into the browser and connect to localhost:8080
```

Comment: Had the same problem a week ago. I think response.json() returns a promise, too.

Comment: @KaiLehmann Yeah, you need the await thing. But it is already "awaiting" the response and inside the async function.

Comment: What are you using to serve your index.html?

Comment: No, what you return to your .then() is actually a Promise. What says the console.log(data?)?

Comment: @CMS I run `node http-server` on the folder then I connect using the browser into `localhost:8080`

Comment: @KaiLehmann Nothing, the fetch failed as you can see on the XMLHttpRequest log

Comment: Have you tried fetch ("./countryballs.json")? Works in my localhost

Comment: @KaiLehmann Doesn't work for me :/

Comment: @WhiteGlove - this is easy enough to produce in the [plunkr](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue&preview) - it is impossible for us to recreate your issue. If you can create you issue in plunkr then we can help.

Comment: @RandyCasburn http://next.plnkr.co/edit/FYChBHmYBL8Hbp10 It does works! I know my code is right... it's just that GET error... which can't fetch the .json file

Comment: Your response is a simple 404. There are several possibilities: 1) Your server (node) is not set up properly to recognize `.json` as a MIME type or 2) Your path is simply wrong or 3) you have implemented a _catchall_ route on your server that preempts the sending of the file - and since there is no _route_ to that URL, your server thows a 404. (this is the most likely scenario).

Comment: @RandyCasburn Could you please provide a path to follow and solve this situation?

Comment: In the code your using `/scripts`, but in the image and the plnkr your not using a directory, which is it? First, debug why you cant find the file by simply visiting it in your browser, then add the fetch code when you know that sanity check is ok.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Sorry! Good call!

Comment: The image is different that the error messages, which is now different than the question code after the edit. This isn't hard. Your path MUST match the location of the file. It is that easy. You are way over your head with this simple code. You need to find a resource (human or otherwise) to get some of these basic building blocks understood before you continue to get frustrated.

Comment: @RandyCasburn You are right, but when I changed the PATH to check if that was the problem I forgot to update the image. Sorry for the confusion. I will load in a .rar the whole thing so you can test it and tell me if you get the same error.