# Fetch local data : How to fetch by objects's names

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

Today, i was doing a really cool project from frontendMentors, a planets website ! We have to do a 8 pages website (each page contains one planet details), we have the choice between writing every planet data directly in the HTML code, or, we can use a local data.JSON to manage it dynamically.

But, I got a problem:

I want to dynamically, with JS and the included data.JSON, write each planet page. So, i was like "Alright, I have to fetch data.JSON, and precise what planet to fetch, like :

```
fetch(`./data.json/${planetTitle}`)
```

But it obviously doesn't work like that. So, does anyone knows how to do it ?
I'll give further informations like a screen of my JS + a screen of the data.JSON file.

[JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fYnv.png);
[script.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO6S7.png);

Thx in advance !

There is the solution !

[html trick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b3Pn.png)
[script trick 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Kbo.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetching local JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481934/fetching-local-json)

Comment: Is your site hosted on a webserver / localhost (emulated host)?

Comment: IMHO you have 2 choices - at each page   bring all planets  and select one you need or separate json file into 8 with different names and bring one planet

Comment: `Alright, I have to fetch data.JSON, and precise what planet to fetch` only by using a scriptable server that serves the JSON can you pass it parameters, and have the server do the filtering.  If you just have a "local JSON file" then no, you will need to load the whole JSON file and filter it in the client.

Comment: Thanks you really much guys ! You indirectly helped me to resolve my problem. I mean, you gave me an idea for filtering locally. 
I'll update my initial post with 2 more screens to show you how i did the trick !