# How to render a text data from a text file in react js?

Tags: reactjs, text

Can someone please guide me how to get the data from a text file in react js? Usually the data extracted from the API is in JSON format but this time I want to render the data that is in .txt file format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse through local JSON file in React js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649695/how-can-i-parse-through-local-json-file-in-react-js)

Comment: No, it is a JSON file but I have a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for you to display a doc text like o told me using simple html and css you can use this exemple:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".word").fancybox({
  'width': 600, // or whatever
  'height': 320,
  'type': 'iframe'
 });
}); //  ready
```

```html
<a class="word" href="//docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.picssel.com/demos/downloads/Fancybox.doc&embedded=true">Open a Word document in Fancybox</a>
```

Comment: I am getting this error now. Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/sample.txt' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Comment: but i do get JSON data with it when converting to JSON where there is 'text'.

Comment: you really have to work white txt? why not json?

Comment: Yes, I have to work with text file as the data available to me is in text format. Is there any possibility to do it successfully?

Comment: so the error has now gone with the help of { mode: "no-cors" } but i am getting "undefined".

Comment: i have edited the code, i'm geting the results really nice from local txt file using the require file, have a look

Comment: @xiang i have added a link for working code, i hope it helps

Comment: that is ok but we won't be able to play around with that as we can with the JSON data. I mean, like this can we able to show some of the text at some place in the browser and skip the rest just like we do with the JSON data? I hope you understood what i mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235579/discussion-between-noobdev-gbl-and-xiang).