# JavaScript ES6 JSON import syntax

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack

I try to write my code in ES6 standard but when I try to import a .json
it fails on me.

```
import JsonT from "../../Data/t.json" //not working

var JsonT = require('../../Data/t.json'); //working
```

Can someone explain what I do wrong?

I use it then like this:

```
console.log(JasonT);
```

Comment: `import` is not supported by Node.JS yet. You can use Babel if you want to use that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6

Comment: @barbsan that question is not about Node.js

Comment: actually i work with ReactJS sorry for the misleading tag?

Comment: could it be issue with `JasonT` instead of `JsonT`?
I see you asked for ```jsonfile = JSON.parse(JasonT);```

Comment: @LEQADA apparently this question also is not about Node.js. @Rudi Have you tried `import JsonT from "../../Data/t"` as suggested in linked question?

Comment: @barbsan yeah removing the .json fixed the problem... didn't think that this would be a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since ES6 is not actually supported on most browsers or JS platforms yet, you will need to use a 'transpiler' like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert your ES6 code into interpretable JavaScript.

If you are using Webpack, you can use [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) to manage this 'transpiling' for you.

If you are just getting started with React, I would recommend using a build config starter like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). This will allow you to get started writing ES6 React code without having to worry about the initial overhead of setting up a build environment.