# Dynamically load JSON information in HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to show all categories from my JSON file in a menu. Can anyone help me with the JavaScript code for this? I have tried a couple of things but all in vain.

HTML: (static)

```
<ul class="cd-faq-categories" id="onderwerp">
     <li><a class="selected" href="#algemeen">Test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#1">Test2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#2">Test3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#3">Test4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#4">Test5</a></li>
</ul> <!-- cd-faq-categories -->
```

JSON structure:

```
 {
    "id": 3,
    "category": "Eten",
    "question": "Vis",
    "answer": "Ham",
    "date": "29-11-18"
  }
```

Can anyone help me with this? I'm trying to have the name and href the same in the HTML tag, so for example:

```
<li><a href="${category}">$c{category}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working solution:

```
var data =[
    {
      "id": 3,
      "category": "Eten",
      "question": "Vis",
      "answer": "Ham",
      "date": "29-11-18"
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
      "category": "Eten 2",
      "question": "Vis",
      "answer": "Ham",
      "date": "29-11-18"
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
      "category": "Eten 3",
      "question": "Vis",
      "answer": "Ham",
      "date": "29-11-18"
  }
]

const liTemplate = (category) => `<a href="${category}">${category}</a>`

data.forEach(item => {
    var child = document.createElement('li');
    child.innerHTML = liTemplate(item.category);
    document.querySelectorAll('.cd-faq-categories')[0].appendChild(child);
})
```

The solution is taking Json object. Iterate through all items and append to DOM li elements with simple vanilla JS appendChild method.

Comment: And with this fiddle you can remove duplicates for categories: https://jsfiddle.net/dvubg2pc/8/

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This work within the file but I have the JSON objects in a different file. How can I make it take all the categories from that seperate file?

Comment: Depends on your setup, you ca use ajax to get json file content and then use JSON.parse to create javascript object from it. 

if you are using webpack you can simple import that json to your file.

it depends.

Comment: This should help in case your are using es6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6

Comment: Alright I got it to work. And to bother with a final thingy: how can I sort the display in alphabetic order? I tried the sort function but it gives an error.

Comment: Could you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554661/sort-data-with-javascript when you have time. I'm trying your code for the sorting for that too but it doesn't seem to work. I tried editing some stuff from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON file is a just a text file, so in order javascript to understand it like an obj. you must parse it. You must use JSON.parse() function.  

var data = JSON.parse('{
        "id": 3,
        "category": "Eten",
        "question": "Vis",
        "answer": "Ham",
        "date": "29-11-18"
    },');

<li><a href="${data.category}">$c{data.category}</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to have all the categories I used in my complete JSON file to load in the menu so that when I used 6 different categories it will load in 6 times the `<li>`. If I have the same category multiple times in the JSON file it needs to only load that particular category once.