# Sort data with JavaScript alphabetically

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort the categories shown with this code. Does anyone know how to? It reads a JSON document with the following structure:

```
`"id" = "test" 
"question" = "test" 
"answer" = "test" 
"category" = "test"`
```

All the categories must be displayed in alphabetic order. The categories in the example are 'Soda' 'Apple' and 'Cat'. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```js
function sortByCategory(data) {
                    return data.reduce((obj, c) => {
                        const { category, ...rest } = c;
                        obj[category] = obj[category] || [];
                        obj[category].push(rest);
                        return obj;
                    }, {});
                }

                // Returns the question/answer HTML 
                function buildQuestionHTML(arr) {

                    // Iterate over the category array objects
                    return arr.map(el => {

                        // In each case return the question/answer HTML
                        return `
                  <li class="block">
                    <a class="cd-faq-trigger" href="${el.id}">${el.question}</a>
                    <div class="cd-faq-content">
                      <p>${el.answer}</p>
                    </div> 
                  </li>
                `

                        // Making sure we join up the final array
                    }).join('');
                }

                // Returns all the HTML from the categorised data
                function buildPageHTML(data) {

                    // Iterate over the categorised data
                    return Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, c) => {

                        // Get the question/answer HTML
                        const questionHTML = buildQuestionHTML(data[c]);

                        // Create the scaffold for the category and
                        // add the category name, and question/answer HTML
                        const html = `
                  <li id="${c}" class="cd-faq-title">
                    <h2>${c}</h2>
                  </li>
                  ${questionHTML}
                `;
                        acc.push(html);
                        return acc;

                        // We're adding the HTML to an array so we need
                        // to ensure we join it up into a string
                    }, []).join('');
                }

                function displayQuestions() {

                    // Get the data
                    // This would normally be a call to your server which 
                    // would return some JSON data
                    $.getJSON("/json.json", function (data) {

                        // create a string of the object 
                        data = JSON.stringify(data);

                        // Parse the data
                        const questions = JSON.parse(data);

                        // Sort the data by category
                        const categoryData = sortByCategory(questions);

                        // Get the root element where you want the compiled data to be added
                        const root = document.getElementById('algemeen');

                        // Build the HTML
                        const html = buildPageHTML(categoryData);

                        // Add it to the root element
                        root.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);


                    });
                }

                // call displayQuestions
                displayQuestions();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
            <html lang="en" class="no-js">
            
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
                <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
                <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
                <script src="js/alerts.js"></script> <!-- Many Alerts -->
                <title>FAQ</title>
            </head>
            
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="#"><img class="" src="images/.png"></a>
                <div class="navbar-right">
                    <a href="-"><img
                            class="language" src="images/.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    <body>
       <section class="cd-faq">
            <ul class="cd-faq-categories" id="onderwerp">
    
            </ul> <!-- cd-faq-categories -->
    
<ul id="algemeen" class="cd-faq-group">
            </ul>
    </section> <!-- cd-faq -->
    
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.document.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Credits for the JS code to @Andy.

Comment: No reference to jQuery included into page header?

Comment: And it would've been helpful if you post your html as well

Comment: @ygorbunkov It's added now.

Comment: You are already sorting all questions by their categories. Is the question about sorting them alphabetically?

Comment: @SrishtiGupta Yes

Comment: I think it may be a problem because it puts all the content in `<ul id="algemeen" class="cd-faq-group"></ul>` while it should make a different <ul> for each category (including all the questions and answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you with sorting categories alphabetically:

```
// function to sort categories alphabetically
// place this function inside your JavaScript file where you have written all your code
function sortCategoriesAlphabetically(data) {
    return Object.keys(data).sort().reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        accumulator[currentValue] = data[currentValue];
        return accumulator;
    }, {});
}

// the following two lines are part of your **displayQuestions** function
// Sort the data by category (already written by you)
let categoryData = sortByCategory(questions);

// Sort categories alphabetically (to be added below the above line)
categoryData = sortCategoriesAlphabetically(categoryData);
```

Comment: Where exactly should I place the code? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: @Steven Edited the answer to help you where exactly the code has to be written.

Comment: That makes the content disappear

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. It's working fine. Fiddle for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/de5ocubn/

Comment: It seems to work perfect with the JSON in the text itself, but I read it from an extern json file. It doesn't seem to go in the correct order using that

Comment: There is a problem when you are reading the contents of the file then.