# Import JSON file inside a ES6 supported project

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I'm getting a it confused here. In a VueJS project I'm using a dummy json data in the following way :

```
import data from './assets/data.json'
```

which i can than print to the screen, for example   : `{{Object.keys(data)}}`

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6)
question i find different answers, some claim you **cant** import json files, some claim you **can**
. common sense implies that i can import them since it is working in my project, now the  question is:
is this some Webpack magic helping me to achieve this import or any other behavior taking place under the hood? or is ES6 actually allows me to import json as presented above?

Comment: ES6 only specifies importing ES6 modules (scripts with `export` declarations and stuff), so yes this a feature of your module loader.

Comment: typically you would use the fetch api.  here is an example with vue and axios: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Comment: You can but you should not as it may be a problem when you are reading and also writing in JSON file in run time.
if you will read JSON using import then updated data will not reflect in your object.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 0):

Please go through,
[How to import a json file in ecmascript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6)

Says,

> ES6/ES2015 doesn't support loading JSON via the module import syntax

Comment: i actually intended to link to this question but mistakenly linked to another one. as you can see there, while the second answer by Simone claims "Unfortunately ES6/ES2015 doesn't support loading JSON via the module import syntax" , the 5th answer by @Wiliamli claims "In ES6/ES2015, you can import json file in your code."