# Javascript Import Don't Work In Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, import, javascript-import

I can't import anything in my javascript files of my website, I've tried many things but it doesn't work.

So I want to import a .json file to a .js file using the `import` key word but it doesn't work. Another problem is that Visual Studio Code doesn't show me an error but the console does...

### main.js import part

```
import dropDownList from "./navigationList.json"; //This is line number 1

console.log(dropDownList.shop.kits);
```

### navigationList.json file

```
{
    "shop": {
        "kits": "DIY Physics Kits",
        "merch": "Merchendise"
    },

    "learn": {
        "first-sub": "Mechanics",
        "second-sub": "Miscellaneous"
    }
}
```

### Error the console is showing:

`mainJS.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

The console says there is an Uncaught SyntaxError with my import and this causing me to make my code long and without import which sucks.
**Please help me**

Comment: `import` keyword doesnt work with importing json data, it can only import defined modules from js file. See documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import and workaround - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6/39855320

Comment: use the `fetch` api to get your JSON.

Comment: @Sarwara - this: _import keyword doesn't work with importing json data_ is not accurate. One can import JSON **data** as long as it is exported. But, one cannot import from a MIME type other than JS (i.e navigationList.json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `import` syntax is part of ES6 modules. It looks like you are using Node.js, which does not include support for ES6 modules by default. However, [Node.js has experimental support for ES6 modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

1. Rename the file to have an `.mjs` extension:

```
mv mainJS.js mainJS.mjs
```

2. Run it with the `--experimental-modules` flag:

```
node --experimental-modules mainJS.mjs
```

I tested this with your code, and it works:

```
% node --experimental-modules main.mjs
(node:73044) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
DIY Physics Kits
```

At the time of this writing, I am using Node.js v12.3.1:

```
% node --version
v12.3.1
```

Alternatively, you can transpile your code with a tool like Babel, which changes `import`s to `require`s.

Comment: Hey Elliot you really helped me altough I am not using Node.js, this scripts are connected to my web page with the ```<script>``` tag, However I will try to transpile my code in order to use ```require()``` and I will see if it works. Note: Currently when I am trying to use the word ```require()``` in my code the console says that ```require is not defined```.

Comment: By the way: This article says that without a server I can't use the ```import``` keyword, and currently I am running my website on my computer with the protocol ```file://``` so I guess that was the main problem...

Answer (score 1):

**navigation_list.json**

```
{
    "shop": {
        "kits": "DIY Physics Kits",
        "merch": "Merchendise"
    },

    "learn": {
        "first-sub": "Mechanics",
        "second-sub": "Miscellaneous"
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```
var navigation_list = require('./navigation_list.json');
console.log(`>>>> Returned JSON data: ${navigation_list.shop.kits}`);
```

[End the output here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN9sb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set "type": "commonjs" in package.json