# Loading strings from external source in Javascript list

Tags: javascript, mysql, xml

I'm looking for the proper way to load strings into `Javascript` code.

For example if I have about 300 strings like this one:

```
 '<h1>Some text</h1>'
```

I want to load from some external source with loading of `page.php`  into `JS` script.

I want avoid listing of strings as variables `var v1 = '<h1>Some text</h1>';` or in list `var lst = ["<h1>Some text</h1>", "<h1>Some text2</h1>"];` included to `.js`, but load strings to array from outside.

One way is using of `MySQL` database given the fact that static sequence is important to use `ID` for assigning string values to special variables.

But I'm not sure if connection with database is a best, fast and soft way for this particular case, when list is not too big, requires static sequence, not dynamically updated and must be outside of `.js` document and loaded in to array with page load.

I don’t see the point of loading from one `.js` to another `.js`, if my goal is remove listing from `.js`. Мaybe I can use `.xml`, or something else, more suitable what is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could do so by putting those strings into a Json file

Your Json file (myData.json):

```
{
 "textOne": "Some text",
 "textTwo": "Some text",
 "textThree": "Some text",
}
```

Your Javascript:

```
const messages= require('./myData.json');


const messageOne = messages.textOne;
```

Comment: just to make it clear, I've added `myData.json` in same directory with `myJs.js`, is that correct? Because  `const messages = require('./myData.json');` throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. So, if `require()` is not a feature that is built into the browser, then what should I use in this case

Comment: you will need NodeJs to use require. If you want to import json without NodeJs, you could use import . You may refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6