# How to fix warnings on imported json file?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In my vue project, I have a json file that I import into my script (typescript) with `import jsonData from '@/assets/data1.json';`

I can access its data and it works fine, but during the build I'm getting a ton of *warnings* like this one:

```
WARNING in /path/src/assets/data1.json
1:1 unused expression, expected an assignment or function call
  > 1 | {
      | ^
    2 |     "x123": {
    3 |         "name": "John Doe",
    4 |         "confirmed": true
```

What should I do to tell the compiler that the file is actually a **json** file and not javascript/typescript?

To get this to work I've already added

```
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
```

to `tsconfig.json` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50830840/86845

Comment: this seems like a lint warning to me, are you using TSLint and do you have a `tslint.json` in your project?

Comment: @DavidPorcel yes I do. What should I change in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this warning by excluding json files on your `tslint.json` file like this:

`"linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "*.json",
      "**/*.json"
    ]
  }`

the `**` is for it to be recursive

Comment: You were right. But I've only added the `"**/*.json"` rule. `**/` usually means any directory depth (including zero), so I thought the other entry shouldn't be necessary.