# Fetching data from local json file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch-api

I have a problem with the module not being found in React import. Here is my API from the file:

```
[   
    {
        "poolNumber": "1",
        "sender": "Damir",
        "notRoutedReason": "NumberDoesntExist",
        "sentDateTime": "2019-08-13T08:01:48.1535075Z",
        "requestedDeliveryReportMaskText": "Submitted",
        "deliveryReportReceivedDateTime": "2019-08-13T08:01:48.1535075Z",
        "isUnicode": "FALSE",
        "messageUUID": "4889e632-a314-45e2-89fd-35b07b4f9ff2"
    },
    {
        "poolNumber": "1",
        "sender": "Damir",
        "notRoutedReason": "NumberDoesntExist",
        "sentDateTime": "2019-08-13T08:01:46.3254032Z",
        "requestedDeliveryReportMaskText": "Submitted",
        "deliveryReportReceivedDateTime": "2019-08-13T08:01:46.3254032Z",
        "isUnicode": "FALSE",
        "messageUUID": "7f48626f-7dfe-4772-99e6-3a4c1df15e0e"
    }
]
```

And then I'm trying to call it under imports so I can log(data)..

```
import React from 'react'

import dataJSON from './data.json'
    const getData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(dataJSON)
        const data = await response;
        return getData
    }
```

But I can't fetch data coz it isn't getting module I need.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What bundler are you using? For example, create-react-app uses webpack + some configurations that should allow you to easily import json

Comment: I don't think you need to use fetch to import a local json file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a json file in ecmascript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: I'm using webpack from create-react-app... is there some solution to fix config for importing json file...

Comment: @messerbill Tried that solution.. and got err Expected a JSON object, array or literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tnx all for trying to help me, but my solution was putting .json file in public folder, and importing it in App.js... that Way engine didn't trow error and I resolved it with async/await.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) this should work fine :

```
import dataJSON from './data.json'

console.log(dataJSON )
```

Comment: Doesn't work... It gives me error saying that it can't find module... But it works If I declare file with js extension and export default dataJSON...

Comment: That's strange, usually installing 'json-loader' module solves this, but CRA already has  that, maybe you're using an old version of CRA, try `npm install --save-dev json-loader`

Comment: Did it already... But have the same error... I will do It as a js file, and just export default let dataJSON and stringify it in component... Is that a good solution?

Comment: yeah that'll work, but it's not what u wanted in first place :)

Comment: It's not, but I'm sick of trying to find why doesn't it work as it should... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use axios / Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js to handle the request in the React componentDidMount life-cycle method.

https://github.com/axios/axios

But I agree that in CreatReactApp is easier to just:

```
import info from './data.json';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using create-react-app, just import

```
import dataJson from './dataJson.json';
```

Please see my sandbox [import json in react app](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-frost-bsigw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: It doesn't see JSON as a module... I've tried that in the first place, knowing what and how should it work, but it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

For use import and export statements, you have to use es6, and for this, babal is required.

Maybe you have to add babel-plugin-import to your project: [read if you have and how to install and configure here here)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import)

Comment: I have babel instaled by creating an app with react-create-app, so it isn't that...