# Does the ES modules implementation support importing JSON files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I couldn't find any answers on importing JSON files with the new ES modules implementation, all the answers that I've found on StackOverflow are for code that's transpiled using Babel, I want to import my `package.json` file:

```js
import pkg from '../package.json';
```

And I'm getting this error:

```sh
(node:7863) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/run_main.js:54
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".json" for /home/user/files/project/package.json imported from /home/user/files/project/version.js
    at Loader.resolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:126:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:72:33)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:156:40)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

I'm using the latest **Node.js 13.6.0**, am I only left with the option to read the file using the `fs` module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a json file in ecmascript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: Um, JSON isn't Javascript, so why would you think that it would? Just read the file and parse the contents.

Comment: @JustinWorkman Actually no, I've checked all the answers and none of them worked for me, I wanted to check if there's a solution other than reading the file.

Comment: @Pierre you have two options: read the file and parse the contents, or use a loader like webpack that deals with non-JS assets (not appropriate for a node project, obvs). Ecmascript modules are for, well, *Ecmascript*, JSON is completely different.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60206393/1653236

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've found in the [Node.js ES Modules docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_experimental_json_modules) that currently importing JSON is only supported in the CommonJS mode and the flag `--experimental-json-modules` is required for importing JSON files in ES modules.

> Assuming an index.mjs with

```
import packageConfig from './package.json';
```

> The --experimental-json-modules flag is needed for the module to work.

```
node index.mjs # fails
node --experimental-json-modules index.mjs # works
```

Comment: That is *really terrible*, what a slap in the face to portability. Ah well, looks like you got your answer, +1.

Answer (score -11):

You can import it as so:

```
import *  as config from '../config.json'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem, you will still get the same error about a wrong file extension

Comment: * as config is literally a legacy.