# Import '.json' extension in ES6 Node.js throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

We're trying to use the new ways of exporting and importing modules for ES6 with Node.js. It's important for us to get the version number from the `package.json` file. The following code should do that:

```js
import {name, version} from '../../package.json'
```

However, on execution the following error is thrown:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".json" for T:\ICP\package.json imported from T:\ICP\src\controllers\about.js
```

Is there something we're missing?
Is the extension `.json` not supported?
Is there another way to retrieve this information using Node.js 13+?

Comment: Do you have a json file in that path? Have you tried other ways to import like `import pkg from ('../../package.json')`?

Comment: Yes, the `.json` file location is correct.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

From Node.js version 17.5.0 onward, importing a JSON file is possible using [Import Assertions](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#json-modules):

```js
import packageFile from "../../package.json" assert { type: "json" };

const {
    name,
    version
  } = packageFile;
```

- `assert { type: "json" }` is mandatory
- Destructuring such as `{ name, version }` is not possible in the `import` declaration directly
- The contents of the JSON file are exported as a default export, so they need to be imported from `default`.

The dynamic import version looks like this:

```js
const {
    default: {
      name,
      version
    }
  } = await import("../../package.json", {
    assert: {
      type: "json"
    }
  });
```

Since [import assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions) and [JSON modules](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-modules) have only recently promoted to stage 3, older versions of Node.js might have supported an older syntax.
According to the compatibility tables on MDN for [`import` declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#browser_compatibility) and [dynamic `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import#browser_compatibility), older versions of Node.js (16.0.0 – 16.14.0 and 17.0.0 – 17.4.0) had varying support:

- These versions required the `--experimental-json-modules` flag:

  ```bash
  node --experimental-json-modules about.js
  ```
- Some versions did not support import assertions on dynamic `import`
- Some versions did not support the `"json"` type, specifically
- Some versions relied on an older proposal which did not specify the `assert` syntax yet

Comment: Hii Idder, Even  I got the same error after adding the flag . yarn run dev --experimental-json-modules that's the script is used to run my project

Comment: But it's annoying to add that flag every time. Can it be set permanently?

Comment: @Kokodoko You can add the flag to one of your startup scripts in package.json.

Answer (score 64):

You can sill import `require` in an ES6 module for Node.js:

```
import { createRequire } from "module"; // Bring in the ability to create the 'require' method
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url); // construct the require method
const my_json_file = require("path/to/json/your-json-file.json") // use the require method
```

Comment: Node.Js v15 lastest give me this error `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: @CAlonsoCOrtega We are creating the `require` on line 2 of my answer. If it is undefined, you must have skipped the first few lines.

Answer (score 28):

You can use it as in docs [node-js](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_json_module_loading) as follow:

```
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';

const json = JSON.parse(await readFile(new URL('../../package.json', import.meta.url)));
```

Comment: If you're doing this on a server... I highly recommend the cleaner `fs-extra`, which promises everything transparently and supports recursive directory copy

Comment: eslint throws error on this as the `await` keyword can only be used within `async` functions

Answer (score 22):

## 2022

From Node.js [v16](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/esm.html#json-modules) & [v18](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/esm.html#json-modules) official documentation:

```js
import SomeJson from './some.json' assert { type: 'json' }
```

And run it with the matching experimental flag:

```bash
node --experimental-json-modules ./your-file.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when compiling using Vite. Not even changing `with` to `asset` worked for me, I had to change the file from `.json` to `.js` and add `export default` at the beginning of the file to be able to import the data.

For me, this was the solution and it also simplified all the NodeJS syntax bureaucracy.

Answer (score -15):

try to use

```
process.env.npm_package_version
```

[this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153571/is-there-a-way-to-get-version-from-package-json-in-nodejs-code)

Comment: This will only work if the app is started with `npm`, which is not always the case.

Comment: did you try using fs to load the file ?

Comment: That seems to be bad practice as it loads the complete file which shows the dependencies and other information that mekes the app vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: This feature will probably be removed... due to the mentioned security concerns, and the lack of support for deno and qbrt