# How should I import JSON in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to import `package.json` into `test.js`, both files are in same directory.

I tried with `require` :

```
const jsonfile = require("./packages.json");

console.log({ jsonfile });
```

it throws error:

```
file:///home/.../test.js:1
const jsonfile = require("./packages.json");
                 ^
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///home/.../test.js:1:18
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:145:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:182:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

This error implies, like it runs in browser, where is no `require`,  I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/196241) with similar message.

I tried with `import`:

```
import * as jsonfile from './packages.json';

console.log({ jsonfile });
```

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/.../packages.json' imported from /home/.../test.js
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:271:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:694:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:784:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:100:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:246:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:47:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:46:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

What I have tried more?

- Single quotes and double quote around filename
- filename with extension and without.
- with flag [--experimental-json-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60206393/196241)
- [adding `"type":"module`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45854500/196241) into `package.json` (but this is for Node >= 13, but without it I got warning `(node:7170) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.` and then also error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`)

I found even suggestions to load JSON-file as regular text files and parse them into data structure, but this seems like the last resort...

It seems such a trivial task, but I have not found the idiomatic way how to import JSON-data into Javascript variable. What is wrong here? How should I import it?

I use Node 12.21.0

Comment: You should be able to `require` a json file in Node, not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: The current LTS for Node is 14, and the current stable is 15, so at the very least you probably want to update to 14, but if you _have_ to use 12: you're not writing ES module code, why would you try to force Node into running your code as if it is? Just run `node test.js` (not `node test`), and your code will run just fine.

Comment: `require("./file.json");` should work. Is it just a typo? package**s**.json vs. package.json?

Comment: @simon.ro yes, it was just typo here, in actual code it was `package.json`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for pointing out old version, seems reasonable to upgrade. And I run always with extension.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're using Node.js in ESM mode, ESM does not currently import JSON modules by default. You can either:

1. Turn on JSON module importing (by passing a CLI flag)
   OR
2. Create a `require` function in your ESM code and use that OR
3. JSON.parse the file manually

#### Turn on JSON module importing (by passing a CLI flag)

You can do that by passing the [`--experimental-json-modules`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_experimental_json_modules) flag.

```js
node --experimental-json-modules yourfile.js # can import JSON here
```

#### Create a `require` function in your ESM code

You can also always fall back on CommonJS modules and create a `require` of your own:

```js
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
require('./package.json'); // now works
```

#### JSON.parse the file manually

You can always just read JSON files with regular filesystem methods:

```js
# const fs = require('fs');
import * as fs from 'fs';
const result = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));
```

Comment: I am not sure if `--experimental-json-modules` works on Node.js 12, so you might be down to `createRequire`.

Comment: I can confirm: all those 3 variants work fine. With flag `--experimental-json-modules` I did not include extension (was './package'). Thank you!

Comment: ESM doesn't just not "currently" support JSON, it will never support JSON =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans JSON modules reached stage 3 in last month https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-modules#json-modules and is currently in-development in Chrome https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5749863620804608 . anything you know I don't regarding the chances of it shipping in browsers or being unflagged? (If TC39 ships it, we'll 100% ship it in Node.js)

Comment: interesting, I thought it got shot down as proposal, guess that changed since last time I looked.

Answer (score 4):

You want to import `package.json` but in your code you tried to import `packages.json` (there is a typo).

Note that when you use ESM (`import ... from ...` syntax), you cannot import .json files directly and require will not be defined (on nodejs), while in CJS you can load a json file with `require(...)` syntax (see https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_json_module_loading).

Also, note that you can create a CJS file which imports a JSON file and exports its content, so you can later import it from an ESM file.

**pkg.cjs** (CJS)

```js
const pkg = require('./package.json');
module.exports = pkg;
```

**index.mjs** (ESM)

```js
import pkg from './pkg.cjs';
console.info(`Starting ${pkg.name} v${pkg.version}`);
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add context here for those who may be upgrading from node 12 to 16, as I am doing for some AWS stuff I have running.

I found this --> https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/esm.html#import-assertions when dealing with import assertions.

Worked for me as I am working through and upgrading my project to use the new import syntax.

Which means you could just

```
import jsonfileData from './packages.json' assert { type: 'json' };
```

and it should work.  Again, assuming you are upgrading your project to 16.

Thanks,

~Rob

Answer (score 0):

The import syntax should be always working, but in this case you are requiting it wrong.
Try import jsonfile from './packages.json';.
Youn don't need the * in this case

Comment: Actually, I tried your version first and forgot to mention it in OP

Answer (score 0):

## Don't.

Convert that JSON into a JavaScript object and save that file as `.mjs` and import it like normal. For example:

#### MIME_TYPES.json

```
{
  "default": "application/octet-stream",
  "aac": "audio/aac",
  "bin": "application/octet-stream",
  "bmp": "image/bmp",
  "css": "text/css",
  "csv": "text/csv"
}
```

### Converts to MIME_TYPES.mjs

```
export default {
  default: 'application/octet-stream',
  aac: 'audio/aac',
  bin: 'application/octet-stream',
  bmp: 'image/bmp',
  css: 'text/css',
  csv: 'text/csv'
}
```

Then just `import MIME_TYPES from './MIME_TYPES.mjs';`