# TypeScript cannot import .json

Tags: json, typescript, import, module, ts-node

I am trying import a JSON file into a TypeScript script using `await import(filepath)` but am receiving the following error running script with `npx ts-node <script>`:

```
"CustomError: ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION .json /path/to/file.json"
```

This is the code I use to import the file:

```
const serAcc: ServiceAccount = await import(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, {assert: { type: "json" });
```

where `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is a string.

[These release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html) have some information about adding an assert property to dynamic imports.

The following is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true
    },
    "include": ["src", "utility/test.ts", "utility/tests", "organize.js", "index.ts"]
}
```

This is my directory structure:

```
- tsconfig.json
- utility:
  - storageScripts:
    - uploadFile.ts
```

I am calling the file from the root directory with:

```bash
npx ts-node ./utility/storageScripts/uploadFile.ts
```

Is there something wrong with my tsconfig.json that is causing improper module resolution? I set my module Resolution to "Node", and resolveJsonModule and isolatedModule to true which I have seen helped others with similar issues.

I have also had issues with importing .ts files as well when running scripts with `npx ts-node`, but if I specify that the files are `.ts` files, there is no error:

```
// @ts-ignore
import { object } from "file.ts"
```

**How can I import .json files to a TypeScript script using ts-node**

Thanks

Comment: Do [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205891/import-json-extension-in-es6-node-js-throws-an-error) answer your question?

Comment: @AlexWayne I saw that discussion, but using that tag with ts-node does not work. I also added an assert property to my import function parameters (updated in my question) that still causes the same error.

Comment: Hey Matthew, I have the same problem.. did you manage to find a solution to this issue? Thanks !

Comment: I wasn't able to use the `import` keyword, but for now I have been using fs.readFileSync() from the `fs` module

Comment: Eg: jsonObject = `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("path/to/file.json"))`