# Typescript can't import json

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, import

I simply can't import json files in a NodeJS v18 project. I am using TS 4.8.4 and i have in the tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "target": "esnext",
  "lib": ["esnext"],
  "module": "commonjs",
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "strict": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true
}
```

In index.ts i have:

```
import * as json from '../config.json';
console.log(json);
```

I already saw many answers in stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72723144/typescript-cannot-import-json) but i can discover what seems to be the problem.
Any suggestions? Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I keep going in circles. The TS compile gives errors and suggest to change the module. I change the module than the import does not anymore. I can't find a solution for this.

**UPDATE**
Changing the module to nodenext in the tsconfig, the import of the json file works BUT the import of other TS files do not work anymore:
error TS2835: Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in

```
EcmaScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'. Did you mean './myclass.js'?
```

What else do i need to change now? Thank you.

Comment: try `import json from '../config.json'`

Comment: What exactly does _"I simply can't import json"_ mean? Does it throw any error?

Comment: Medet, that did not work. But chaing the module to nodenext in tsconfig worked but the import of TS classes do not work anymore....

Answer (score 0):

In the import, you have mentioned "import * as json from '../config.json';"
instead of that try "import * as json from './config.json';"
Or you can also try using absolute path for the json just for testing purpose.

Comment: that did not work either.