# Read settings contained in a json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Im tring to read a simple setting from a json file, the json is this :

```
{
  "Label": "some string here"
}
```

form my javascript part i do:

```
import settings from '../settings.json';
```

then:

```
  var settings= ()=> { 
      const headers = new Headers();
      const requestOptions = {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { ...headers.authentication, ...headers.culture, 'ContentType':'application/json',
          };
    return fetch(`${settings.Label}`, requestOptions).then(() => {
           return response.text().then(text => {
                  const data = text ? text && JSON.parse(text) : {};
                  let token = response.headers.get('X-Token');
                  if (token) {
                      data.token = token;
                  }
                  if (!response.ok) {
                     // manage error here
                  }
                  return Promise.reject(error);
           }
          return data;
        })
      });
    };
    // use settings here
```

Despite my many searches and attempts  im not very expert in javascript,i have tried in many ways before, but the my variable 'settings' is not contain nothing.

Comment: Two things. 1: fetch returns a Promise, not "the value". Just because you're returning the subsequent `then` doesn't mean your code's going to wait for that unless you use `await` (see the async/await docs on MDN for information on how to do that). 2: why are you using the same name for that import and your var?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `.Label` from your fetch method and do ```fetch(`${settings}`,..``` instead? Secondly, you are using the name `settings` as the identifier for the `/settings.json`, (which makes `settings` global to that file` and you also named the function `settings` too. That's conflicting

Comment: Are you using webpack or babel?
This may be of use... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6

Comment: change the name of the imported json `settings` or the `var settings`, cuz this might cause unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had completely wrong the approach, the file is already available and I don't have to request to download it from the server, I just have to return string, without use of fetch or other:

```
return (`${settings.Label}`
```

Sorry and thank a lot for the support

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add an export to your JSON file

```
export const settings = {
 "label": "some string here"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much information given here, but this probably has to do with transpiling your javascript. You can use:

```
const settings = require('../settings.json')
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59844868/7701381

Also, change the name of the imported json settings or the var settings, cuz this might cause unexpected behaviors