# How to read json data from local file to my react js application into an list?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, html-lists

I am actually trying to build an application where json data will be present in a local file on my system. I would like that data to be added into my reactjs application inside a list.
can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a json file in ecmascript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: Hi, I think this is a duplicate and may find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6