# Import a mock JSON file for Jest/Axios upload test

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios

I am looking to test Axios functionality of a method which posts a file using Jest.

As part of this I would like to POST a local mocked JSON file, is that possible?

I can't see any way to require or import a JSON file for uploading in a POST.

```
// import jsonFileMock from "../__mocks__/jsonFileMock.json"; 
import jsonFileMock = require("../__mocks__/jsonFileMock.json"); 

const apiResponse = await someApiUpload(jsonFileMock); // Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing ES6 `import` with commonjs `require`.  Try

```js
import * as jsonFileMock from "../__mocks__/jsonFileMock.json"
```

A json file can't have an export statement, so thats why you have to use the `* as` term.  You can also just fetch it:

```js
fetch('../__mocks__/jsonFileMock.json')
  .then( async data => await someApiUpload(data) )
```

More about importing a json file can be found in the question [How to import a json file in ecmascript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: Thanks I did read that thread but it was more to do with reading the contents of the file rather than uploading it, I will give fetch a go now.

Comment: Jest doesn't like fetch apparently, I'm not convinced using wildcard * with import will work to be honest.

Comment: I understand, but you can't upload data coming from your `import jsonFileMock = require("../__mocks__/jsonFileMock.json");` statement, as that statement doesn't make sense to javascript

Comment: Yup, that's about where I got to with it as well :)