# Map function in class component react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React and I'm trying to iterate through a json file, want to render the objects by using the map function.
However it doesn't display the objects. Can someone please tell me want I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import stations from './test.json';



export default class Playlist extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            allStations: [stations],

        };

    }



    render() {
        return (

            <View>
                {this.state.allStations.map((item, index) => (
                    (
                        <View>
                            <Text>{item.firstName}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )
                ))}

            </View>




        )
    }
}
```

This is my json file:

```
[{
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName": "Jackson",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 28

   
 },
 {
    "firstName": "Brad",
    "lastName": "Brown",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 45
   
   
 }
]
```

Comment: You need to spread the stations `allStations: [...stations]`.

Comment: Also, the way you import JSON is not correct. pleas see https://stackoverflow.com/q/34944099/14032355

Answer (score -2):

Add your "test.json" file inside an assets folder and assign it to an index.js file, so when you have more files you can add them under assets and export them from a single location

[Have a look into this code, Thankyou](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqLVF.jpg)

For more information on how to use the map() function https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-the-map()-function-to-export-javascript-in-react