# Hook into NextJS server startup

Tags: next.js, config

How do I hook into the startup of a NextJS server so that I can do one-off initialization?

There's a [discussion here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11686) but so far no solution.

Comment: if you have your own rollup, you can `npm i -D @rollup/plugin-json`. But if you don't have your own build, then maybe the easiest is to convert it into a js file. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6 for all options.

Comment: Here's a discussion along the lines of what I'm looking for: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11686

Answer (score 3):

Just add your code to the `next.config.js` file.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
//next.config.js
//imports

module.exports = async (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
    const nextConfig = {...}
    console.log("Executes at server startup")
    return nextConfig
}
```

Comment: This one works, thank you!! It does seem to run multiple times in next dev, but it only runs once on startup in the actual production build

Comment: @dominik you're correct, I've noticed this in Next too. For example, whenever a component is mounted in DEV Next unmounts and remounts directly (check console.log in useEffect).
You can read about it here: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state
Not sure if the multiple runs you see is in any way related to this specifically, but many times next automatically tries to simulate specific scenarios and you might see odd behaviour because of that (only in dev).

Comment: If you add "things" to config, the concept of "plugins" feels appropriate. Here an example: https://github.com/tamagui/tamagui/blob/master/starters/next-expo-solito/apps/next/next.config.js

Comment: @FabianSvensson unfortunately, this is not working for us: we build with output "standalone" and start with `node server.js`. This is next's server.js which is obviously created at build time and contains the hard coded config object. Could you maybe add more details of your config?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [instrumention.ts(or .js)](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation) file from nextjs official documentation

This is basically, we export a function named register in a file called instrumention (js/ts) in root directory of your project. In the src/ directory if you use one. Nextjs looks for the file and calls the function whenever server instance is bootstrapped.

1. First add a config to you next.config.js file like below

*next.config.js*

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: { instrumentationHook: true },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

2. Then write any logic you want to run on server startup
   Below is a sample *instrumention.ts* file.
   I wrote register function with a simple scheduled task
   which logs datetime on every 2 secs.

*instrumentation.ts*

```js
export function register() {
  setInterval(() => console.log(new Date()), 2000)
}
```

Save the file and restart the server.
The output only updates on restarting the server. else the previous code will run if you had one in instrumentation.ts file.

now you can see the output below.

Output
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVa2k.png)

> Read the full doc
> [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solution will solve your problem.

[This is an example of the startup function in next JS with not custom server](https://github.com/Pig-Cola/next-js-init-function)

This repository run startup function without using custom server.
Before and after the next JS is loaded, it can be executed respectively.

```js
// before next loading

console.log(process.env.ENV_TEST, '[expected]: undefined') // undefined

// after next loading

const command = process.argv[2]
if (['dev', 'start'].includes(command)) {
  require('./node_modules/next/dist/bin/next')
  check(init)
}

// function
// function
// function

// next loading check
/** @param {Function} fn */
function check(fn) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!('LOAD_CHECK' in process.env)) {
      setTimeout(check, 0, fn)
      return
    }
    fn()
  }, 50)
}

// after init function
function init() {
  switch (command) {
    case 'dev': {
      // here dev script
      console.log('run dev')
      break
    }
    case 'start': {
      // here start script
      console.log('run start')
      break
    }
  }
  // commons script
  console.log(process.env.ENV_TEST, '[expected]: Hello!!') // 'Hello!!'
}
```

For more information, see the [app.js in this repository](https://github.com/Pig-Cola/next-js-init-function/blob/main/app.js)

Answer (score 0):

i am using instrumentation.js/ts  file , so it run before server starts ,if anyone want to call api, this is not possible because server is not started yet. i am calling asynchronous call so it will let server to start.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW0Hd.png)