# Reading json file on javascript return error

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to read a big json file with JS

```
const jsonFile = JSON.parse("3BP-OOP-PFR.json");
console.log(jsonFile);
```

The problem is

> VM334:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 1
> at JSON.parse ()
> at main.js:1:23

Comment: I don't think that anyone here can help you without seeing the file you're trying to read ;)

Comment: [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) takes a JSON string, not a file name. `3BP-OOP-PFR.json` is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: it's a big json generated by pandas export

Comment: Well, ignore my first line. `JSON.parse` expects a json string and not a filename

Comment: so @DM how I can read the file first please?

Comment: @Collaxd [How to import a JSON file in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: Please can you post your json file data here, if its big you may post as a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing the filename as JSON, which will fail. The `JSON.parse` function expects a JSON string value to parse, not a file.

Have you tried importing the file instead?

```js
import jsonFile from "3BP-OOP-PFR.json";

console.log(jsonFile);
```

If you are using a browser, you will need to fetch the file:

```js
fetch('https://website.com/subdir/3BP-OOP-PFR.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

If you want to use `async`/`await`:

```js
const res = await fetch('https://website.com/subdir/3BP-OOP-PFR.json')
const json = await res.json();
console.log(json);
```

Keep-in-mind that if you are fetching a JSON file locally, this will fail. Make sure you are using a webserver and running off of `localhost`. I believe there are flags that you can pass (CLI) to the browser to override the local file loading error.

Comment: hey! ty, but now my error is

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at main.js:1:1)

Comment: I updated the response to include a browser scenario.

Comment: ok this solution works, but how I can put into a var?

Comment: const data = fetch('https://website.com/subdir/3BP-OOP-PFR.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))

Comment: I need to acess it and later do something like data.flop["0] etc etc @Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: @Collaxd you can destructure the JSON properties as variables.

Comment: look,
let response;
const data = fetch("3BPOOPPFR.json")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => (response = json));

console.log(response);

returns undefined

if clear see the code please and ty alot
https://i.imgur.com/r4IL6s3.png
https://i.imgur.com/LcThqYR.png

Comment: and yes, i Just use it local

Comment: @Collaxd the promise is asynchronous. You will not be able to access the `response` that you store inside the promise—outside of it. You will need to await the promise or pass-in a callback. Your follow-on issues fall the scope of this question. Please open a new question with your *new* problem.