# Error: Cannot find module '../swagger.json' in an NX workspace

Tags: json, typescript, express, nx-monorepo

I am unable to import any .json files in my express app inside an NX workspace.
This is my import statement

```
import swaggerDocument from '../swagger.json';
```

and my project structure

```
tsconfig.base.json
apps
|- test-app
  |- swagger.json
  |- tsconfig.json
  |- tsconfig.app.json
  |- src
    |- main.ts   <-- import statement here
```

this is my `tsconfig.base.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      ...paths for other modules
    },
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

and `tsconfig.app.json`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["node"],
  },
  "exclude": ["jest.config.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

so what am I doing wrong here? I have also tried placing the .json file inside the /src dir and import from there, but no success.

Comment: I know you have a bounty on this so I don't want to waste your time but importing json using ES6 is a known hurdle with documented help. Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using TypeScript, you already have `"resolveJsonModule": true` set in your `tsconfig.json`, which would allow you to import JSON files when you transpile your TypeScript to JavaScript.
However, due to the [current limitations with ESM in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34944099/6309), you would still face issues at runtime.

The import assertion proposal is still [marked as experimental in Node 18/19/20](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/esm.html#import-assertions).

The [OP mdakovac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783738/mdakovac) points to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34946395/6309) as the main solution:

> If you're using Webpack, importing of JSON files will work by default (since webpack >= v2.0.0).
>
> ```js
> import config from '../config.json';
> ```

---

If I repurpose [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75183039/6309) to your use case:

#### Option 1: Read and parse JSON files manually

You can use Node.js's file system module to read the JSON file and then parse it to a JavaScript object.
Your `main.ts` would be:

```js
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';

async function main() {
  const json = JSON.parse(
    await readFile(
      new URL('../swagger.json', import.meta.url)
    )
  );
  console.log(json);
}

main();
```

#### Option 2: Leverage the CommonJS `require` function to load JSON files

You can use [`createRequire`](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#module_module_createrequire_filename) to construct a CommonJS `require` function, which would then allow you to load JSON files in your ECMAScript modules.

```js
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const swaggerDocument = require('../swagger.json');
```

Comment: At the top where you show my project structure, you got it wrong - main.ts is inside the /src folder so my import statement is correct.

By going over the links you provided, I found my issue is that I'm not using webpack, which is why imports in other similar projects worked. Please add the webpack info from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34946395/1783738 for completion and then I'm marking it as solved.

Comment: Good points. I have fixed the import path, and included the answer you mention (about webpack)