# "Unexpected token, expected" when I tried to get value from .json file for k6 script JS

Tags: javascript, k6

I have a JSON file with some values

```json
{
    "1": "socks",
    "2": "jeans",
    "3": "hoody"
}
```

I'm trying to get random value from this file

```
import { sleep, group, check } from "k6";
import http from "k6/http";
import { checkCode } from "./mainFunction.js";
import searchWords from "../data/searchWords.json";


let duration='1m';
let maxVUs = 100;
let randomNumber = function (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};
let response;
let searchId = randomNumber(1, 27);
let searchWord = searchWords[searchId];
let searchUrl = encodeURIComponent(searchWord);
```

and when I run a script I got error and I don't understand how to fix it

```
ERRO[0000] SyntaxError: file:///Users/malekulo/Testing/data/searchWords.json: Unexpected token, expected ; (2:7)
  1 | {
> 2 |     "1": "socks",
    |        ^
  3 |     "2": "jeans",
  4 |     "3": "hoody"   
    at <internal/k6/compiler/lib/babel.min.js>:7:10099(24)
    at <internal/k6/compiler/lib/babel.min.js>:5:29529(56)
    at h (<internal/k6/compiler/lib/babel.min.js>:4:30563(6))
    at bound  (native)
    at s (<internal/k6/compiler/lib/babel.min.js>:1:1327(8))  hint="script exception"
```

Comment: [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: You cannot import JSON in a Javascript file like that. You could be forgiven for thinking that you could: there are *code processing tools* that can do that (e.g. webpack, rollup, vite), so you will find copious examples of people doing that on the internet. But you can't do that in raw JS.

Comment: There is no difference in access wrt myObject[numericProperty] and myArray[numericIndex] so I would suggest you use an array since it seems a better fit for your data, especially if you're going to be selecting a random element.

Answer (score 1):

k6 does not support importing json.

You can use `open` and get the same thing though as in

```js
const searchWords = JSON.parse(open("../data/searchWords.json"));
```

Just be careful as this file will be open and loaded for *each* VU you have, so if it is 1mb file and you have 1000 VUs it will use a lot more than 1GB of memory as it also needs memory for the objects.

If the file is a big array you can use [SharedArray](https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/javascript-api/k6-data/sharedarray/) as in

```js
import { SharedArray } from 'k6/data';
const searchWords = new SharedArray('searchWords', function () {
    return JSON.parse(open("../data/searchWords.json"));
});
```

As that will significantly cut on the number of *full* copies in memory