# Import JSON file in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to import a JSON `DATA` variable from an external file. I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot find module "./customData.json"

Could some one help me? It works if I have my `DATA` variable in `index.js` but not when it's in an external JSON file.

index.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import customData from './customData.json';
import Profile from './components/profile';
import Hobbies from './components/hobbies';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Profile name={this.props.profileData.name}imgUrl={this.props.profileData.imgURL} />
        <Hobbies hobbyList={this.props.profileData.hobbyList}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App profileData={DATA}/>, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

hobbies.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

var Hobbies = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var hobbies = this.props.hobbyList.map(function(hobby, index){
        return (<li key={index}>{hobby}</li>);
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <h5>My hobbies:</h5>
            <ul>
                {hobbies}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
  } 
});

export default Hobbies;
```

profile.js

```
import React from 'react';

var Profile = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
            <img src={this.props.imgUrl} />
        </div>
    )
  }
});

export default Profile
```

customData.json

```
var DATA = {    
    name: 'John Smith',
    imgURL: 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/',
    hobbyList: ['coding', 'writing', 'skiing']
}

export default DATA
```

Comment: Your customData.json is not a JSON.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

A nice way to do this would be using the `json-loader` module. This way you don't need to add a fake `.js` extension (which is intended for code rather than data/config). **This module is already included in `create-react-app` and Webpack 2.x+** (current version is 5.x), so if you use any of these tools, you can easily import your json without any additional configs/dependencies:

```
import Profile from './components/profile';
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33650470/1990785) answer for more details.

Comment: Strange. When I try to import a json file in `create-react-app`, it returns `undefined`

Comment: IMHO, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52349546/76583) should be really the accepted answer. This one is indeed a solution but only for a subset of React apps - only the ones started with create-react-app.

Comment: fyi, this works. except I had an edge case where the json file cannot have an underscore in it's name. i.e. `/profile.json` is ok, but `/my_profile.json` is not.

Comment: @Seb See my last edit. This solution also applies to all projects that use Webpack - which is most of the react apps today and majority of all web apps really. Also, you can add the `json-loader` module to any web app even if it don't use webpack, so it has no limitations.

Answer (score 102):

This old chestnut...

In short, you should be using require and letting node handle the parsing as part of the require call, not outsourcing it to a 3rd party module. You should also be taking care that your configs are bulletproof, which means you should check the returned data carefully.

But for brevity's sake, consider the following example:

For Example, let's say I have a config file 'admins.json' in the root of my app containing the following:

admins.json

```
[{
  "userName": "tech1337",
  "passSalted": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}]
```

Note the quoted keys, `"userName"`, `"passSalted"`!

I can do the following and get the data out of the file with ease.

```
let admins = require('~/app/admins.json');
console.log(admins[0].userName);
```

Now the data is in and can be used as a regular (or array of) object.

Comment: Definitely the correct answer. Shouldn't need a third-party module to read in JSON data.

Comment: The double quotes around the keys are required for properly formatted JSON. Also, JSON can not have comments.

Comment: This is the way to go

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to load a JSON file in a React app.  There is no "Node" in a React app.  What you might want to suggest is having the JSON payload served by the back-end and making a call to it, but telling them to use `require` doesn't help the OP at all.

Comment: I wrote this answer a while back, and it does indeed make some assumptions and glosses over the options available for implementing `require` in your React or other JS framework application.

It may be poorly worded, but I was eluding to the Node `require` syntax more than Node.js itself.

The default CRA config will transpile `require` for the web, but you could also use `browserify` instead to the same effect.

Comment: @LICON99 this may be what's happening in your code. Just you did not show it.

Answer (score 20):

With [`json-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader) installed, you can use

```
import customData from '../customData.json';
```

or also, even more simply

```
import customData from '../customData';
```

To install [`json-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader)

```
npm install --save-dev json-loader
```

Answer (score 20):

React 17 created from `create-react-app`, importing json just work by default.

```js
import config from './config.json'
```

Answer (score 17):

Simplest approach is following

```
// Save this as someJson.js
const someJson = {
  name: 'Name',
  age: 20
}

export default someJson
```

then

```
import someJson from './someJson'
```

Comment: This is not a JSON.

Comment: This is a JavaScript object not a JSON object

Answer (score 11):

The solution that worked for me is that:-
I moved my data.json file from src to public directory.
Then used fetch API to fetch the file

```
fetch('./data.json').then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
      // Work with JSON data here
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(err => {
      // Do something for an error here
      console.log("Error Reading data " + err);
    });
```

The problem was that after compiling react app the fetch request looks for the file at URL "http://localhost:3000/data.json" which is actually the public directory of my react app. But unfortunately while compiling react app data.json file is not moved from src to public directory. So we have to explicitly move data.json file from src to public directory.

Answer (score 10):

Please store your JSON file with the .js extension and make sure that your JSON should be in same directory.

Comment: Solved !! Thanks for the answer !!

Answer (score 10):

In current react build you simply import and use:

```
import jsonData from 'path/to/myJson.json'
```

Answer (score 8):

// rename the .json file to .js and keep in src folder

Declare the json object as a variable

```
var customData = {
   "key":"value"
};
```

Export it using module.exports

`module.exports = customData;`

From the component that needs it, make sure to back out two folders deep

`import customData from '../customData';`

Answer (score 7):

try with `export default DATA` or  `module.exports = DATA`

Comment: uhm have you tried with require instead of import ? but i'm pretty sure that this is not the problem, the path is correct?
oh and try also to write import DATA instead of customData.

Answer (score 7):

there are multiple ways to do this without using any third-party code or libraries (the recommended way).

1st STATIC WAY: create a .json file then import it in your react component example

my file name is "example.json"

```
{"example" : "my text"}
```

the example key inside the example.json can be anything just keep in mind to use double quotes to prevent future issues.

How to import in react component

```
import myJson from "jsonlocation";
```

and you can use it anywhere like this

```
myJson.example
```

now there are a few things to consider. With this method, you are forced to declare your import at the top of the page and cannot dynamically import anything.

Now, what about if we want to dynamically import the JSON data? example a multi-language support website?

2 DYNAMIC WAY

1st declare your JSON file exactly like my example above

but this time we are importing the data differently.

```
let language = require('./en.json');
```

this can access the same way.

but wait where is the dynamic load?

here is how to load the JSON dynamically

```
let language = require(`./${variable}.json`);
```

now make sure all your JSON files are within the same directory

here you can use the JSON the same way as the first example

```
myJson.example
```

what changed? the way we import because it is the only thing we really need.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
var langs={
  ar_AR:require('./locale/ar_AR.json'),
  cs_CZ:require('./locale/cs_CZ.json'),
  de_DE:require('./locale/de_DE.json'),
  el_GR:require('./locale/el_GR.json'),
  en_GB:require('./locale/en_GB.json'),
  es_ES:require('./locale/es_ES.json'),
  fr_FR:require('./locale/fr_FR.json'),
  hu_HU:require('./locale/hu_HU.json')
}
module.exports=langs;
```

Require it in your module:

```
let langs=require('./languages');
```

regards

Answer (score 2):

My friends, if you are using **`React`** and **`TypeScript`**, just do these steps and **DONE**!

1. In the **`tsconfig.json`** add these 2 new lines:

   ```
    // tsconfig.json
    {
       "compilerOptions": {
          // ... other options
          "esModuleInterop": true,
          "resolveJsonModule": true
        }
    }
   ```
2. Import your json:

   ```
   import yourJSON from "./data/yourJSON.json"
   ```

Answer (score -1):

This worked well in `React 16.11.0`

```
// in customData.js
export const customData = {
  //json data here
  name: 'John Smith',
  imgURL: 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/',
  hobbyList: ['coding', 'writing', 'skiing']
}
```

```
// in index.js
import { customData } from './customData';

// example usage later in index.js
<p>{customData.name}</p>
```

Comment: This is not a JSON

Comment: @Rambalac the customData.js file contains json. We import that file into index.js

Comment: The problem that JSON has it's own strict specification and this simple JS file doesn't fulfill these criteria. So your solution is just a handling of the standard JS file that contains JSON. It's like a workaround but it doesn't provide an answer regarding Topic. It's like: `Please, give to me a suggestion what is the faster bus to Maiami?  Well, just buy an airline ticket`. Both do the same but there is a nuance

Answer (score -2):

Something that worked for me was to simply place the JSON file in the public folder. You can simply import in any js using

```
brain.loadData("exampleFile.json");
```

It is as simple as that I guess. Definitely worth a try :D

Comment: what is `brain` ? this looks like a method on something that is doing a http fetch ?

Comment: I just used `brain` as an example. It is actually an ml5.js instance. But during import, I was not able to access the json even after importing. Putting the json file in public folder helped me access it.