# React set image src to a dynamic path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, src

So what I an trying to do is to read image-src from a JSON file.
In the JSON file I have something like this:

```
{
   posts:[
           {"img": "../images/a.png"},
           {"img": "../images/b.png"},

           //and more... 
         ]

}
```

Then I am trying to use these paths as image src in react:

```
import data from '../posts.json';

<img src={require(data.posts[0].img)}/>
```

This does not work, I get this error: Error: Cannot find module ".".
Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: Make sure the path is correct.

Comment: Path is correct I have tried a static path, and it worked.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686035/import-json-file-in-react

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t use `require` there.

```
<img src={ data.posts[0].img }/>
```

Comment: I dont get any error with your solution, but the image does not show up. In the chrome debugger, I see that the path is written correctly, but no image is displayed, this has something to do with webpack. When using require with a static path it works, but not with dynamic path.