# Display data from a local JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

I'm learning to code in React from [Tyler Mcginnis' React course](https://tylermcginnis.com/courses/react/) (which I strongly recommend btw) and I decided to develop my own project, a university administration website, which can be displayed in different languages.

So far, I have developed the Login page, please **note that I'm using Babel**:

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { languagedata } from './Languages'
import languagesdata from '../languagesdata.json'

function LanguagesNav ({ selected, onUpdateLanguage}) {
  const languages = ['EU', 'ES', 'EN']

  return (
    <div >
      <h1 className='center-text header-lg'>
        GAUR 2.0
      </h1>
      <ul className='flex-center'>
        {languages.map((language) => (
          <li key={language}>
            <button
              className='btn-clear nav-link'
              style={language === selected ? { color: 'rgb(187, 46, 31)' } : null }
              onClick={() => onUpdateLanguage(language)}>
              {language}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

LanguagesNav.propTypes = {
  selected: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onUpdateLanguage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      selectedLanguage: 'EU'
    }

    this.updateLanguage = this.updateLanguage.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    this.updateLanguage(this.state.selectedLanguage)
  }
  updateLanguage (selectedLanguage) {
    this.setState({
      selectedLanguage
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedLanguage } = this.state
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <LanguagesNav
          selected={selectedLanguage}
          onUpdateLanguage={this.updateLanguage}
        />
        <form className='column player'>
          <label htmlFor='username' className='player-label'>
            //Just testing whether JSON can be displayed
            { languagesdata.data }
          </label>
          <div className='row player-inputs'>
            <input
              type='text'
              id='username'
              className='input-light'
              placeholder='Erabiltzailea'
              autoComplete='off'
            />
          </div>
          <div className='row player-inputs'>
            <input
              type='password'
              id='username'
              className='input-light'
              placeholder='Pasahitza'
              autoComplete='off'
            />
          </div>
          <div className='row player-inputs'>
            <button
              className='btn dark-btn'
              type='submit'
            >
              Sartu
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

}
```

[image: website login interface]

I would like to display the website in the selected language based on the information stored in a local JSON file:

```
 [
  {
    "EU": {
      "welcome": "Sartu GAUR 2.0ra",
      "login": "Sartu"
    },
    "ES": {
      "welcome": "Entra a GAUR 2.0",
      "login": "Entrar"
    },
    "EN":{
      "welcome": "Log into GAUR 2.0",
      "login": "Log in"
    }
  }
]
```

I've tried several solutions that I've found on the Internet, but none of them worked for me.

I've tried importing a Javascript file that contains a JSON data (see below) and importing a JSON file itself (see JSON above).

```
const languagedata = {
  "data": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "euskara": {
          welcome: "Sartu GAUR 2.0ra",
          login: "Sartu"
        },
        "español": {
          welcome: "Entra a GAUR 2.0",
          login: "Entrar"
        },
        "english":{
          welcome: "Log into GAUR 2.0",
          login: "Log in"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Thus, I have 2 questions:

- What would be the best way to do what I'm trying to do?
- How can I display the JSON data in Login.js?

Comment: It's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686035/import-json-file-in-react/51933994). Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm already importing the file using json-loader as specified in the link, however, I'm not sure how to display the data in Login.js. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data from json file you have to make a request to that file.

```js
class App extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <div>geting json data</div>
    );
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('YOUR-JSON-FILE-PATH')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

OR You can use a synchronous way,

```
const data = require("YOUR-JSON-FILE-PATH");
```

Hope it can help!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, correct me if I'm wrong but I think this wouldn't apply as you're fetching the data from a web repository.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're only missing `export` keyword in your Languages.js file:

```
export const languagedata = {
  "data": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "euskara": {
          welcome: "Sartu GAUR 2.0ra",
          login: "Sartu"
        },
        "español": {
          welcome: "Entra a GAUR 2.0",
          login: "Entrar"
        },
        "english":{
          welcome: "Log into GAUR 2.0",
          login: "Log in"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Now you should be able to import variable `languagedata` in your React component using

```
import { languagedata } from './Languages'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried that but I don't see any of the data. Perhaps I'm not calling the data correctly from Login.js?

Comment: You definitely have ```Language.js``` file in same directory as is your ```Login.js``` file? Are you using webpack as a development server?

Comment: Yes, I do have them in the same directory, and yes, I am using webpack as a development server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have json-loader module. If you're using create-react-app, it will come by default.

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686035/import-json-file-in-react/51933994).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm already importing the file using json-loader as specified in the link, however, I'm not sure how to display the data in Login.js. Any idea?