# How to pass data into a component from a json file automatically?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, blogs

I'm trying to build a react website blog. I have a JSON file that has all my posts in. I want to pass the data to my blogSelction component. The goal is to have different cards and in each card have the data from the JSON. There will be a different blog post in a different div. I would like it so when I add to the JSON file it automatically makes a card post that you can click on.

I was just wondering what is the best way to go about making the code for it, I am a complete newbie so it might be really simple I'm just uneducated in the topic.

How I have tried to do it is useState and useEffect for the computer to know the directory; using it so the code knows where to look. After its in-state, I use the map call and try it get the posts but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Card from "../../Card";
import blogPost from "../../../data/blog.json";

const BlogCards = (props) => {
  const [post, setpost] = useState([]);
  const [blogs, setblogs] = useState([
    {
      id: "",
      blogCategory: "",
      blogTitle: "",
      postedOn: "",
      author: "",
      blogImage: "",
      blogText: "",
      blogText2: "",
      blogText3: "",
      blogText4: "",
    },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const blogs = blogPost.data;
    setblogs(blogs);
  }, [blogs]);

  if (blogs.blogImage == "") return null;

  return (
    <div className="item-1">
      <article className="IndividualArticles">
        <Card>
          {blogs.map((blog) => {
            return (
              <NavLink key={blog.id} className="Link" to={`/post/${post.id}`}>
                <div>
                  <h1>{blog.blogTitle}</h1>
                  <p>{blog.blogText}</p>
                  <span>Posted on {blog.postedOn}</span>
                </div>
              </NavLink>
            );
          })}
        </Card>
      </article>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogCards;
```

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "blogCategory": "",
            "blogTitle" : ".",
            "postedOn" : "06/08/2020",
            "author": "Robert Lawson ",
            "blogImage" : "",
            "blogText" : "",
            "blogText2" : "",
            "blogText3" : "",
            "blogText4" : ""
        },
 {
            "id": 2,
            "blogCategory": "",
            "blogTitle" : ".",
            "postedOn" : "06/08/2020",
            "author": "Robert Lawson ",
            "blogImage" : "",
            "blogText" : "",
            "blogText2" : "",
            "blogText3" : "",
            "blogText4" : ""
        },
 {
            "id": 3,
            "blogCategory": "",
            "blogTitle" : ".",
            "postedOn" : "06/08/2020",
            "author": "Robert Lawson ",
            "blogImage" : "",
            "blogText" : "",
            "blogText2" : "",
            "blogText3" : "",
            "blogText4" : ""
        },
 {
            "id": 4,
            "blogCategory": "",
            "blogTitle" : ".",
            "postedOn" : "06/08/2020",
            "author": "Robert Lawson ",
            "blogImage" : "",
            "blogText" : "",
            "blogText2" : "",
            "blogText3" : "",
            "blogText4" : ""
        },
 {
            "id": 5,
            "blogCategory": "",
            "blogTitle" : ".",
            "postedOn" : "06/08/2020",
            "author": "Robert Lawson ",
            "blogImage" : "",
            "blogText" : "",
            "blogText2" : "",
            "blogText3" : "",
            "blogText4" : ""
        },
 {
            "id": 6,
            "blogCategory": "",
            "blogTitle" : ".",
            "postedOn" : "06/08/2020",
            "author": "Robert Lawson ",
            "blogImage" : "",
            "blogText" : "",
            "blogText2" : "",
            "blogText3" : "",
            "blogText4" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I've taken all the data out of the JSON because of the volume of writing.

---Not code related ---
While I'm posting on here I would also like to learn how to be more articulate in the programming field so I can express my self better posting on stack overflow + speaking to developers if you have any tips or advice it would be much appreciated.

Comment: please post some code that you tried and try to narrow down the question to what doesnt work for you

Comment: I guess this would help you with your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686035/import-json-file-in-react

Comment: Could you share a sample content for the json file

Comment: It seems like something is wrong with your json. Could you please share your json file?

Comment: I have posted the JSON with empty strings, it would be too big to post otherwise If you need to see the full one let me know. It doesn't come up with any errors though.