# React-intl parse json array in locale file

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, formatjs

I'm currently working with `React-intl v. ^4.7.6`. I have a folder called `translations` where all my locale translations are in. I use `IntlProvider` to select which file to load based on the user's browser. It seems like `FormatttedMessage` or `intl.formatMessage` can't do this.

Here is what my translation file looks like. Of course, there would be one for every language.
`transtions/eng.json`

```
{
  "header.about": "About",
  "header.resume": "Resume",
  "Education": [{
    "school": "ABC University",
    "degree": "(B.Eng)",
    "graduated": "2030 - Present",
    "location": "Canada",
    "description": [
      "d1",
      "d2"
    ]
  },
    {
      "school": "College",
      "degree": "Science",
      "graduated": "2030",
      "location": "Canada",
      "description": [
        "Graduated with honors"
      ]
    }]

[... other translations ...]
}
```

Comment: Does this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45662052/9449426) help you? Are you using CRA or/and typescript?

Comment: I'm using typescript but unfortunately this is not helping. The Json file is loaded by `IntlProvider` based on the user's browser language

Comment: If you're using typescript, check if you have `resolveJsonModule` set to true in your `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach to resolve your problem. (Though it might not be the best solution and it is not exactly using your en/ german translate, but i think they are similar)

First we can define a file with all localization keys:

```
// i18n/keys.js 
export const student = {
 
  projects: [
    {
      name: "student.projects.0.name",
      desc: "student.projects.0.desc",
    },
    {
      name: "student.projects.1.name",
      desc: "student.projects.1.desc",
    },
  ],
};

export const localizationKeys = {
  student: student,
};
```

In i18n locale files, we can define the translations as below:

```
// i18n/en/student.js
export const student = {
  projects: [
    {
      name: "Camera",
      desc: "Photo",
    },
    {
      name: "Foods",
      desc: "Apple",
    },
  ],
};

// i18n/zh_tw/student.js
export const student = {
  projects: [
    {
      name: "拍攝",
      desc: "照片",
    },
    {
      name: "食物",
      desc: "蘋果",
    },
  ],
};
```

Export the translations in i18n to locale modules for react-i18n

```
// i18n/en/index.js
import { student } from "./student";

const en = {
  general: general,
};

export default en;

// i18n/zh_tw/index.js
import { student } from "./student";

const zh_tw = {
  student: student,
};

export default zh_tw;
```

In your react components, you can access your localization Keys (keys.js) to get back each of the i18n keys name.

```
import React from "react";
import { useIntl } from "react-intl";
import { localizationKeys } from "./i18n/keys";
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";
import zh_tw from "./i18n/zh_tw";
import flatten from "flat";
import en from "./i18n/en";

const messages = {
  en: flatten(en),
  "zh-Hant-TW": flatten(zh_tw),
};

export default function ProjectShowcase() => {
  const intl = useIntl();
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState(navigator.language);
  const [mergedMessages, setMergedMessages] = useState(messages["en"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Merging english and current locale, avoid showing Text id if cannot look for the translate in locale file
    // In this case, it will always show EN translate as default if the text-id not found in a "zh_tw" locale
    setMergedMessages(Object.assign({}, messages["en"], messages[locale]));
  }, [locale]);
  
  return (
  <IntlProvider
      messages={mergedMessages}
      locale={locale}
      key={locale}
      defaultLocale="en"
    >
    {localizationKeys.student.projects.map((p, idx) => {
        return (
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span>
                {intl.formatMessage({
                  id: localizationKeys.student.projects[idx].name,
                })}
              </span>
              {` (${intl.formatMessage({
                id: localizationKeys.student.projects[idx].desc,
              })})`}
            </li>
          </ul>
        );
      })
    }
 </IntlProvider>
  )
}
```

I have developed a little example on the react-intl, you may find more completed code inside: https://github.com/applelok/react-localization

Comment: TL:DR Refactor out arrays outside locale files to obtain similar behavior. Too much work, imo.