# How Can I get data from this json file in React js

Tags: reactjs, json, api, redux

how to get data from this json. I want to get the language_name and language_knowledge_level from this json. The name of my big object is profileCv. I used redux js and wrote with useSelector. How can I do get the data, help me if you can please.

with greatings.

```
{
"languages": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cv/languages/superuser-1642866627530289/",
            "slug": "superuser-1642866627530289",
            "language_name": "English",
            "language_knowledge_level": "sufficient"
        },
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cv/languages/superuser-1642866644119506/",
            "slug": "superuser-1642866644119506",
            "language_name": "Russian",
            "language_knowledge_level": "excellent"
        }
    ],
}{
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import JSON file in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686035/import-json-file-in-react)

Comment: no bro it is not the solvement of my problem.

Comment: pls show us the code you have tried so far and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to give a good sense of what to do:

https://reactgo.com/react-load-json-file/