# Reactjs error reading a Javascript Object Notation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object

I have 2 codes.

1.this giving error:

```
import userdata from "./data.json";
userdata = userdata.userdata;
userdata.map() // do map here.
```

that giving error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userdata')`

2. this works:

```
import userdata from "./data.json";
userdata.userdata.map() // do map here.
```

json:
`{"userdata":[{name, job}, {name, job}]}`

why the second code is working?

Comment: What does `data.json` look like?

Comment: Are both functions called from the same directory? If not, the import for the 1st piece of code might not be pointing to the correct file.

Comment: @kiner_shah example added.

Comment: @adrian both called on the same file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import JSON file in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686035/import-json-file-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example you import `userdata` and then try to assign it the value of userdata.userdata.

**This isn't possible as you can't assign a new value to an import.**

Therefore when you try map over `userdata` it is still trying to map over userdata from the initial import (and not `userdata.userdata`).

If you want this to work rather use a new variable name like below:

```
import userdata from "./data.json";

const userDataArray=userdata.userdata;
userDataArray.map()
```

In the second example, you reference the array correctly (with `userdata.userdata`), instead of trying to assign a value to the import.