# how to import json file in productdetails js file

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native, react-redux, antd

ERROR in ./src/Product/ProductChart.js 11:0-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../db.json' in 'C:\Users\SH20330370\react-demo\src\Product'

i am getting error like this .

```
import db from '../db.json';

i tried to insert this but getting error which is above.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import JSON file in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686035/import-json-file-in-react)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your `db.json` file is in `/src/Product/` folder.

Use this statement `import db from './db.json';`

Comment: no it is outside the src folder.

Comment: @fayazshaik if it is outside the src folder, the path you are using isn't pointing at it.