# tell typescript to compile json files

Tags: json, typescript

The typescript compiler works fine when I import a json file using

```
const tasks = require('./tasks.json')
```

However, when I run `tsc`, the output directory does not contain no `tasks.json` file, causing a runtime error.

Is there a way to tell the compiler that it should copy all json files, or should I manually copy/paste all my json files into the `dist` directory ?

my tsc compilerOptions currently reads

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
```

Thanks !

Comment: This seems like something grunt/gulp would do, not a compiler.

Comment: You do not compile json you would have a gulp/grunt task to move it to your public directory (wwwroot or the like), my advice just keep it in the public directory if it is only needed there then you do not need a move task.

Comment: Gulp or grunt could be used to copy the JSON file to your dist, but you'd still have issues with the `require()` statement at runtime (unless this is actually running in node). See my answer.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

## Problem

For people wanting to copy **all** JSON files, it's really difficult in TypeScript.  Even with `"resolveJsonModule": true`, `tsc` will only copy `.json` files which are **directly referenced** by an `import`.

Here is some example code that wants to do a **dynamic** runtime `require()`.  This can only work if all the JSON files have been copied into the `dist/` folder, which `tsc` [refuses](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30835) to do.

```
// Works
import * as config from './config.default.json';

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

const envConfigFile = `./config.${env}.json`;

// Does not work, because the file was not copied over
if (fs.existsSync(envConfigFile)) {
  const envConfig = require(envConfigFile);
  Object.assign(config, envConfig);
}
```

## Solution 1: Keep json files outside the src tree (recommended)

Assuming you have `/src/` and `/dist/` folders, you could keep your JSON files in the project's `/` folder.  Then a script located at `/src/config/load-config.ts` could do this at runtime:

```
const envConfig = require(`../../config.${env}.json`);

// Or you could read manually without using require
const envConfigFile = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', `config.${env}.json`);
const envConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(envConfigFile, 'utf-8'));
```

This is the simplest solution.  You just need to make sure the necessary config files will be in place in the production environment.

The remaining solutions will deal with the case when you really want to keep the config files in your `src/` folder, and have them appear in your `dist/` folder.

## Solution 2: Manually import all possible files

For the above example we could do:

```
import * as config from './config.default.json';
import * as testingConfig from './config.testing.json';
import * as stagingConfig from './config.staging.json';
import * as productionConfig from './config.production.json';
```

This should cause the specified json files to be copied into the `dist/` folder, so our `require()` should now work.

Disadvantage: If someone wants to add a new `.json` file, then they must also add a new import line.

## Solution 3: Copy json files using tsc-hooks plugin (recommended)

The [`tsc-hooks` plugin](https://github.com/swimauger/tsc-hooks) allows you to copy all files from the src tree to the dist tree, and optionally exclude some.

```js
// Install it into your project
$ yarn add tsc-hooks --dev

// Configure your tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  // This tells tsc to run the hook during/after building
  "hooks": [ "copy-files" ]
  // Process everything except .txt files
  "include": [ "src/**/*" ],
  "exclude": [ "src/**/*.txt" ],
  // Alternatively, process only the specified filetypes
  "include": [ "src/**/*.{ts,js,json}" ],
}
```

I found it tsc-hooks [announced here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30835#issuecomment-850098727).

## Solution 4: Copy json files using an npm build script (recommended)

Before `tsc-hooks`, we could add a [`cpy-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpy-cli) or [`copyfiles`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) step [to the npm build process](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30835#issuecomment-520188747) to copy all `.json` files into the `dist/` folder, after `tsc` has finished.

This assumes you do your builds with `npm run build` or something similar.

For example:

```
$ npm install --save-dev cpy-cli

// To copy just the json files, add this to package.json
"postbuild": "cpy --cwd=src --parents '**/*.json' ../dist/",

// Or to copy everything except TypeScript files
"postbuild": "cpy --cwd=src --parents '**/*' '!**/*.ts' ../dist/",
```

Now `npm run build` should run `tsc`, and afterwards run `cpy`.

Disadvantages:  It requires an extra `devDependency`.  And you must make this part of your build process.

## Solution 5: Use js files instead of json files

Alternatively, don't use `.json` files.  Move them into `.js` files instead, and enable `"allowJs": true` in your `tsconfig.json`.  Then `tsc` will copy the files over for you.

Your new `.js` files will need to look like this: `module.exports = { ... };`

I found this idea [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48409303/99777).

> Note: In order to enable `"allowJs": true` you might *also* need to add `"esModuleInterop": true` and `"declaration": false`, and maybe even `"skipLibCheck": true`.  It depends on your existing setup.

And there is one other concern (sorry I didn't test this):

- Will `tsc` transpile your config files if they are not all statically referenced by other files?  Your files or their folders may need to be referenced explicitly in the `files` or `include` options of your `tsconfig.json`.

## Solution 6: Use ts files instead of json files

Sounds easy, but there are still some concerns to consider:

- Your config files will now look something like this: `const config = { ... }; export default config;`
- See the note above about `files` / `include` options.
- If you load the config files dynamically at runtime, don't forget they will have been transpiled into `.js` files.  So don't go trying to `require()` `.ts` files because they won't be there!
- If someone wants to change a config file, they should do a whole new `tsc` build.  They could hack around with transpiled `.js` files in the `dist` folder, but this should be avoided because the changes may be overwritten by a future build.

## Testing

When experimenting with this, please ***be sure to clear*** your `dist/` folder and `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` file between builds, in order to properly test the process.

(`tsc` does not always clean the `dist/` folder, sometimes it just adds new files to it.  So if you don't remove them, old files left over from earlier experiments may produce misleading results!)

Comment: Beautifully explained!

Comment: Thanks, I took Solution 1 :)

Comment: tsc-hooks does not glob correctly if you have compiler.rootDir set

Comment: Beware, tsc-hooks works by MODIFYING your installed tsc in node_modules, so that it injects its own script. It does not restore tsc when uninstalling tsc-hooks, so you have to restore tsc manually.

Answer (score 33):

In tsconfig.json, add

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "resolveJsonModule": true,
   },
   "include": [
     "src/config/*.json"
  ]
}
```

Notice that it **won't** copy those `json` files which are `require`d. If you need to dynamically require some `json` files and need them to be copied to `dist`, then you need to change from, for example,

```
return require("some.json") as YourType
```

to

```
return (await import("some.json")) as YourType
```

.

Comment: Sorry, my solution was incomplete. Can you try the above and see? The above solution works for me.

Comment: If you want to include all sub - folders, you can use "src/config/**/*.json"

Comment: This was the best solution for me. Note: I had to explicitly have an equivalent line in my include despite the parent folder already being included

Comment: simple and effective

Answer (score 12):

In typescript 2.9+ you can use JSON files directly and it automatically copied to dist directories.

This is `tsconfig.json` with minimum needed configuration:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop"             : true,
        "module"                      : "commonjs",
        "outDir"                      : "./dist",
        "resolveJsonModule"           : true,
        "target"                      : "es6"
    },
    "exclude"        : [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Then you can create a json file.

```json
{
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port"   : 8080
}
```

Sample usage:

```ts
import config from './config.json';

class Main {

    public someMethod(): void {
        console.log(config.port);
    }
}

new Main().someMethod();
```

If you don't use `esModuleInterop` property you should access your json properties encapsulated in default field. `config.default.port`.

Comment: Note that `"resolveJsonModule": true` only copies `import`ed json files. It does not copy _all_ json files, or `require`d json files.

Answer (score 2):

> The typescript compiler works fine when I import a json file using
>
> ```
> const tasks = require('./tasks.json')
> ```

TypeScript wouldn't complain about this as long as you have a global `require()` function defined, for example using [`node.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts#L58). With a vanilla setup you would actually [get a compile error that `require` is not defined](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20a%20%3D%20require(%22foo%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Cannot%20find%20name%20'require').

Even if you've told TypeScript about a global `require` function it just sees it as a function that's expected to return something, it doesn't make the compiler actually analyze what the function is requiring (`"tasks.json"`) and do anything with that file. This is the job of a tool like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Webpack](https://www.webpac.com/), which can parse your code base for `require` statements and load just about anything (JS, CSS, JSON, images, etc) into runtime bundles for distribution.

Taking this a little further, with TypeScript 2.0 you can even tell the TypeScript Compiler about module path patterns that will be resolved and loaded by a bundler (Browserify or Webpack) using [wildcard (`*`) module name declarations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#wildcard-character-in-module-names):

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Now you can import your JSON in TypeScript using ES6 module syntax:

```
import tasks from "./tasks.json";
```

Which will not give any compile error and will transpile down to something like `var tasks = require("./tasks.json")`, and your bundler will be responsible for parsing out the `require` statements and building your bundle including the JSON contents.

Comment: So just do be clear, if we still use the syntax `import tasks from "./tasks.json"` we still need to find some way to get the json file copied over into the outDir directory in tsconfig.json?

Comment: @FrankerZ Correct. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650399/es6-modules-implementation-how-to-load-a-json-file)

Comment: i don't think json-loader helps here, because it expects the javascript itself to have a proper reference to the json?  in this situation the js does not know where the json is, we are copying it to provide it to the js.

Answer (score 0):

you can include this into your build script `&& ncp src/res build/res`, will copy the files directly to your outDir

Answer (score 0):

You can always get an absolute path to your project, with typescript code. To do it just read the JSON file not by the `required` keyword but with the help of the `fs` module. In a path of file use `process.cwd()` to access typescript project directory:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

const task: any = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${process.cwd()}/tasks.json`).toString());
```

To make it work correctly you may need to change your running script to `node dist/src/index.js` where you specify a `dist` folder in the path.