# Is it possible to include a json file when using TypeScript with a tsconfig.json file?

Tags: json, typescript

Is there any way to have the TypeScript compiler also copy content files that don't have a ts or tsx extension to the output directory?

For example, my tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "../../dist",
        "types": [
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "file1.ts",
        "config.json"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "../../node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I would like the `config.json` to end up in my ../../dist directory, but this isn't happening. Is there no concept of a content file for TypeScript?

Comment: Read this article, maybe help you: https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

Comment: OP can you please change the accepted answer

Comment: @dwjohnston I've changed the answer

Answer (score 166, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting `"resolveJsonModule": true` in the compiler options and adding `"source-path/**/*.json"` to the `include` array in the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I had `"source-path/**/*"` in my `"include"` property, which DOES NOT work. As says the [Official tsconfig.json documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) : `If a segment of a glob pattern includes only * or .*, then only files with supported extensions are included (e.g. .ts, .tsx, and .d.ts by default with .js and .jsx if allowJs is set to true).`

Comment: @JRadness this doesn't work for me. Do you have any other compiler options in the tsconfig.json?

Comment: @th3r1singking Here is my whole file currently `{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}`

Comment: Please note that `"resolveJsonModule": true` only copies `import`ed json files. It does not copy _all_ json files, or `require`d json files.

Comment: The strange thing here is that `resolveJsonModule: true` should work by itself, but I find that you must also use `**/*.json`. That is `**/*` is not enough. So you need both...

Comment: Works placing it to the `files` array instead of `include`

Answer (score 17):

I was having the same problem and the solution for this was to add:

```
"source-path/**/*.json"
```

keeping into "includes" array:

```
"source-path/**/*"
```

Example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include":[ 
    "src/**/*",
    "src/**/*.json",
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One workaround is to make the json file a normal js file, require/import it normally, and add `"allowJs" : true` to "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json.

Comment: If you follow that path, you could also convert it to a `config.ts` file, e.g. `export const config = { ... config.json ... }`. And you don't need to set the `allowJs` option.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `tsc` command's job is only to compile .ts files. It doesn't have the capabilities to do build-related tasks that a build system like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) would handle.

For more information, see this similar question: [Angular 2 + Typescript compiler copy html and css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708200/angular-2-typescript-compiler-copy-html-and-css-files)

Comment: Should note that my answer is no longer correct. See higher upvoted one by @Arun-Reddy below.