# Typescript: Unwanted "module.exports =" in JSON file on compile

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, module.exports

In my Typescript app, I have a static JSON file I read-in named `timestamp.json` with this content:

```
{
    "timestamp": "08/14/2019 12:23",
}
```

When I compile the app, the file gets placed in a `/dist` folder with the same name `timestamp.json`, but the content is now different:

```
module.exports = {"timestamp":"08/14/2019 12:23"}
```

This is unexpected and I need the JSON to stay intact. I'm relatively new to Typescript and I haven't been able to find any answers for this online.

Comment: That is not malformed JSON, it is not `prettified`, but it is legal.

Comment: Sorry for misspeaking. While that may be true that is legal JSON, my question still remains. How can I keep the JSON intact?

Comment: You could try exporting a `const` object `timestamp` from a file `timestamp.ts`

Comment: Maybe there is some information for you here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53629381/741850