# Why does tsc not output json files depending on where it's run?

Tags: typescript

Situation: you have a typescript project that's configured to also output JSON files. You have the correct `tsconfig.json` setup and the correct dependencies. You have also read [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471152/tell-typescript-to-compile-json-files) and made sure your typescript files import the json files. Yet, when you run `tsc`, you notice that json files are missing.

Then you copy the project to a separate location, with the exact same file layout, exact same binaries, and run `tsc`. Now, the `json` files get generated. WTFNODE?

Here's a minimal repro, using node v16.13.2 and yarn v1.22.7

## reference project

suppose you have `nodejs` and `yarn` installed at the ready. If using `Nix`, you can achieve this via `nix-shell -p yarn nodejs`. Then:

```bash
pwd
# /tmp/foolib
yarn init -y  # blank project
yarn add typescript  # this is all we need for the repro
export PATH=$(yarn bin):$PATH  # make sure we see `tsc` in the path
```

the remaining files:

### `src/index.ts`

```js
import Thing from './moveme.json'
console.log("Hello")
```

### `src/moveme.json`

```json
{ "foo": "bar" }
```

### `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES2015",
        "declarationMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

if you run `rm -rf dist;export PATH=$(yarn bin):$PATH; tsc; find dist` you should see this output:

```
dist
dist/index.d.ts
dist/index.d.ts.map
dist/moveme.json
dist/index.js
```

## another project

suppose you're importing the project as a library somewhere else. Let's create a fake one this way:

```bash
mkdir /tmp/fooproject
cd /tmp/fooproject
yarn init -y  # this creates package.json, yarn.lock, node_modules
cp -R /tmp/foolib ./node_modules/  # create a local copy
cd node_modules/foolib
tsc
```

now, the output of `find dist`

```
dist
dist/index.d.ts
dist/index.d.ts.map
dist/index.js
```

why is there no `moveme.json`

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

when you are running `tsc` from a location where the real path (after symlinks have been resolved) contains a `node_modules` directory *anywhere* in the hierarchy, the json files will not get copied.

## quick fix

Based on the way `tsc` works, it's probably considered bad practice to ever run `tsc` out of a directory somewhere within `node_modules`. But if at some point you decide to do this, your quickest way out is to compile it at a different location, where `node_modules` is not in the path hierarchy (you can even rename `node_modules` and rename it back).

## explanation

When you call `tsc`, it launches a bunch of async `Worker`s that parse the source files and figure out the code dependency tree. The modules that are referenced in the code (such as the imported JSON file in the above example) are discovered [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/39f5dbff4345e9dbfb30e14917f2dc4a137b6cac/src/compiler/program.ts#L3243) then resolved by worker logic [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/39f5dbff4345e9dbfb30e14917f2dc4a137b6cac/src/compiler/moduleNameResolver.ts#L1329).

So in our example, `processImportedModules()` will discover that `index.ts` imports a *module* called `moveme.json`. The decision of whether to include this file as an output file depends on this line:

```js
const isFromNodeModulesSearch = resolution.isExternalLibraryImport;
```

because it's not getting output, we know `tsc` thinks `moveme.json` is an "external library import". This determination is made by the `tryResolve()` function [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/39f5dbff4345e9dbfb30e14917f2dc4a137b6cac/src/compiler/moduleNameResolver.ts#L1356) and in particular, [this line](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/39f5dbff4345e9dbfb30e14917f2dc4a137b6cac/src/compiler/moduleNameResolver.ts#L1392)

```js
return resolved && toSearchResult({ resolved, isExternalLibraryImport: contains(parts, "node_modules") });
```

finally tells us that any file that's categorized as a "module" whose path contains `node_modules` somewhere in its path will get counted as a an "external library import", and not get copied into the output folder.

After tracing the source, this behavior makes logical sense, but is highly surprising, as the output of what appears to be an isolated project actually depends on the structure all the way to the root of the filesystem. Without this knowledge, `tsc`'s behavior is *inconsistent*; given:

- `inputs0 --{tsc}--> outputs1` from `/tmp/foolib`
- `inputs0 --{tsc}--> outputs2` from `/tmp/fooproject/node_modules/foolib`

here, `outputs1 != outputs2`

*With* this knowledge, `tsc` behavior is *working-directory-dependent*.