# Cannot read json in React.js, unexpected token error

Tags: json, reactjs

I am unable to get the data from a json file in React.js
I have checked myJSON on JSLINT and use a Windows system.

Am not trying to display it yet just storing in a variable, it is still throwing an error :

**ERROR in ./src/app/document.json**

**Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/Ant/Documents/reactapplication/src/app/document.json: Unexpected token, expected ; (2:14)**

```
1 | {
2 |         "name":"Product",
  |               ^
3 |         "properties":
4 |         {
5 |                 "id":
```

Here is my index.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var App = require('./App');
var Json = require('./document');

ReactDOM.render(<div>Hello 123</div>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Am trying to store the json as an object in Json but I am not able to.

My webpack.config

```
var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
output: {
    path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/app/"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js?/,
            include: SRC_DIR,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
                presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
};

module.exports = config;
```

Dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {
"fixed-data-table": "^0.6.4",
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.24.1",
"babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
"webpack": "^2.5.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
}
```

Comment: Maybe try adding the json extension when requiring. `require('./document.json');` webpack by default should be able to import json without any additional loaders.

Comment: Also since you are using webpack you should utilize the es6 import syntax instead of require.

Comment: I tried adding .json as well as using import statement, both are throwing the same error.

Answer (score 4):

**ES6/ES2015**

You could load the JSON using [import as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) syntax:

```
// import the JSON
import * as data from './document.json';
// use the JSON data
console.log(data);
```

**require**

If you are planning to use `require` to import the JSON make sure you are assign the value of the JSON to `module.exports` like this so:

```
// document.js
module.exports = { "id": 1, "name":"foo" };
```

Change the `.json` to a `.js` file type.

That should allow the statement `var Json = require('./document');` to work.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I dont want to modify my json file and use it as is, is there another way of importing json data other than require()

Comment: You would likely need an additional Webpack loader , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650399/es6-modules-implementation-how-to-load-a-json-file

Answer (score 2):

Found the Solution:

Add the following code to loaders in webpack:

```
{ test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
```

Webpack 2.0 by default uses json-loader without having to explicitly call it, this line makes sure that the json-loader renders the file as a json.

You can continue using either of `require()` or `import` to load the json.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding resolve.extensions to your webpack configuration

```
{
    // ...
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['json', 'js', 'jsx'],
    },
    // ...
}
```