# How to fix “Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token” error when using JSON file in react?

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am following a react tutorial by Brian holt and i need to import .json file inside my react component like this :
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4lSc.png)

When I try to build my project i was getting

```
ERROR in ./data.json
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected
```

like this:
[Error caption in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xucDZ.png)

at first i thought that it was an `eslint` issue but it seems that it happens on the build step, i tried adding a `json-loader` to `webpack` but without any success.

**Webpack Version:**
2.6.1

**Babel Core Version:**
6.24.1

**Babel Loader Version:**
7.0.0,
this is my webpack config file :

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
   context: __dirname,
   entry: './js/clientApp',
   devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
   output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/assets/'
   },
   resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', ',json']
   },
   devServer: {
      publicPath: '/public/',
      port: 2110,
      open: true,
      historyApiFallback: true
   },
   stats: {
      colors: true,
      reasons: true,
      chunks: true
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
         },

         {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and this is my **.babelrc** file :

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react", ["env", {
            "targets": {
                "browsers": "last 2 versions"
            },
            "loose": true,
            "modules": false
        }]
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Can you share your data.json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [es6 modules implementation, how to load a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650399/es6-modules-implementation-how-to-load-a-json-file)

Comment: you need to use [`json-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader),  check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33650470/6836839

Comment: i already tried using [www.jsonlint.com] for the JSON validation and  my file passed without any error

Comment: You aren't using `json-loader` please see my previous comment  ^^

Comment: You forgot to add a new rule: `{ test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }`

Comment: @btzr i tried installing the json-loader and the error persists !!

Comment: sorry I just found this: [json-loader is not required anymore](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#json-loader-is-not-required-anymore), indeed that's not the problem...

Comment: thx anyway bro, i hope someone could really resolve this issue

Comment: You have a typo: `extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', ',json']`

Comment: it should be `'.json'`, but try to remove it since you don't need it.

Comment: `extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']`

Comment: i already fix it but no change, always the same error

Comment: can you post the full error message?

Comment: i ve already posted a caption of the error and this is how it is `ERROR in ./data.json
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ; (2:11)

  1 | {
> 2 |     "shows": [
    |            ^
  3 | 
  4 |         {
  5 |             "title": "Atlanta",`

Comment: the problem is this regex: `/\.jsx?/`,  check my answer below...

Answer (score 2):

### Regular Expression

> The test property identifies which file or files should be transformed.

The problem is the regular expression on your rules:

```
{ test: /\.jsx?/ }
```

Your telling webpack to use `babel-loader` with any file extension starting with `.js or .jsx`

So as you can see `.json` match the test.

### Solution

> $ - matches anything until the end of the string

To fix this just replace `?` with `$`, see the example below:

```
 module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
         }
      ]
   }
```

Comment: Thankkkkkk you so much @btzr for your help, that was really a nightmare for me xdxd.