# Import static JSON data in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to load static JSON data to my react app. But, it wan't allow me to load data.

I am using webpack version 4.26.1

It shows me following error:

```
SyntaxError: src/data/movieData.json: Unexpected token, expected ; (2:10)

  1 | {
  2 |     "data": [
    |           ^
  3 |         {
  4 |           "id": 1,
  5 |           "title": "Freed",
```

My Code:

**data/jsonResponse.json**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Freed"
    },
    {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Fifty"
    }
    ]
}
```

**main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Content from './Content';
import  jsonResponse from './data/jsonResponse.json';

class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <Content item={ jsonResponse } />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

**Content.js**

```
import React from 'react';

  const Content = () => {
    const movies = this.props.item.data;
      return (
        movies.map(movie => {
            return (
                <span >{movie.title}</span>
            );
         })
        )
}

export default Content;
```

***Edited:***

If i use js instead of JSON like:

```
const movies_data = {
   "data": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "title": "Freed"
        },
        {
              "id": 2,
              "title": "Fifty"
        }
        ]
    }
export default movies_data;
```

and in Main.js file

```
import  jsonResponse from './data/movieData';
```

Then in browser it shows following error.

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: How your config is setup? Do you use webpack?

Comment: The `import` expects a JavaScript source file, and JSON is not that.

Comment: @MehiShokri Yeah i am using webpack.

Comment: @Pointy What's wrong with importing JSON?

Comment: which version ?

Comment: @kinduser the open `{` in the JSON file is interpreted as the start of a JavaScript block statement. JSON source is simply not JavaScript by itself.

Comment: Please the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650399/es6-modules-implementation-how-to-load-a-json-file/33650470#33650470

Comment: @ jasonlock Doesn't apply. json-loader is loaded by default since >=2.2

Comment: @MehiShokri version 4.26.1

Comment: @Pointy I edited my question

Comment: @ketan answered your question regarding edit.

Comment: @MehiShokri Yeah. Thanks for answer. With Js now working as per Bartek Fryzowicz and you answer so, i up voted both. But, checking with JSON as per your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 workarounds for loading json files in a js file.

1. Rename your json file to .js extension and `export default` your json from there.
2. Since `json-loader` is loaded by default on webpack >= v2.0.0 there's no need to change your webpack configs.
   But you need to load your json file as `json!./data/jsonResponse.json` (pay attention to `json!`)

EDIT:

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

The reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to access `this` on a functional component!

Answer (score 2):

**Answer regarding edited question and `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` error**

You can't access `this` in functional components. `props` are passed as argument to functional components so please try this (`Content.js` file):

```
import React from 'react';

  const Content = (props) => {
    const movies = props.item.data;
      return (
        movies.map(movie => {
            return (
                <span >{movie.title}</span>
            );
         })
        )
}

export default Content;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a [JSON loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/) to import json files.

Comment: json-loader is loaded by default

Comment: Only since version 2 it is :-)

Comment: He mentioned it's 4.7

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if in your Webpack config if exist an loader to JSON.

I recommend to use this loader.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader

Comment: I am using webpack version 4.26.1

Comment: Please provide concrete answer with code snippets. pointing to references per se Does not help. Also, he mentioned he's webpack version is >=2.0.0 so your answer basically does nothing.