# Can't import modules(like axios) and json while require can

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have a simple project like this and have already install axios:
[The project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chhDV.png)

In main.js,I tried to import the axios and a json file but throw error:

```js
import axios from 'axios' //SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
import Test_data from 'json/test.json' //SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

If I use require() it will success,could anybody tell me why?

```js
var axios=require('axios');//success
var Test_data=require('./json/test.json');//success

console.log(Test_data);//success
```

Comment: what node version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 modules implementation, how to load a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650399/es6-modules-implementation-how-to-load-a-json-file)

Answer (score -2):

Try to put attribute `type=“module”` into `script` element in `index.html` file.

```
<script src=“./main.js” type=“module”></script>
```