# React--Looping through a json file, filtering based on a property, and grabbing another property if that condition is met

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a `UScsvjson.json` file which contains covid cases from a start date to an end date for every county for every US state. This is how it looks (for the most part)

```
[
  {
    "UID": 84001001,
    "iso2": "US",
    "iso3": "USA",
    "code3": 840,
    "FIPS": 1001,
    "Admin2": "Autauga",
    "Province_State": "Alabama",
    "Country_Region": "US",
    "Lat": 32.53952745,
    "Long_": -86.64408227,
    "Combined_Key": "Autauga, Alabama, US",
    "1/22/20": 0,
     ... a bunch more dates ...
    "5/27/21": 7141
  },
  {
    "UID": 84001003,
    "iso2": "US",
    "iso3": "USA",
    "code3": 840,
    "FIPS": 1003,
    "Admin2": "Baldwin",
    "Province_State": "Alabama",
    "Country_Region": "US",
    "Lat": 30.72774991,
    "Long_": -87.72207058,
    "Combined_Key": "Baldwin, Alabama, US",
    "1/22/20": 0,
     ... a bunch more dates ...
    "5/27/21": 21606
  },
  ... so on and so on for every county in every state ...
]
```

When I say 'state' I mean a State in the United States, not to be confused with state in React.

I would like for the user to select a US state from a dropdown menu, then based on that US state, retrieve all the counties for that US state in another dropdown menu, something like this:

[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7HN4.png)

so the "County" dropdown would contain Autaga, Baldwin, etc. Essentially, a dropdown containing all of the json's `Admin2` properties, given that the respective json element's `Province_State` matches the US state the user chose in the previous dropdown.

Here is what I have currently for `UnitedStates.js`
:

```
import React from "react";
import * as data from "./us_data/UScsvjson.json";


const CountyList = ({ selectedState, data }) => {

  const countyListForState = JSON.parse(data)
    .filter((state) => (selectedState === state.Province_State))
    .map((state) => state.Admin2);


/*my logic: parse the .json file. filter based on the objects with the same 
Province_State property as our selected US state. 
construct an array of these objects, lets call it US_Object_State_array.
then map each object in the US_Object_State_array to another new array containing only the counties,
and this array will be countyListForState.
then we will construct multiple <option> tags for every county in this array.
*/

  return (
    <div>
      <label>county: </label>
      <select>
        {countyListForState.map((county) => (
          <option value={county.Admin2}>{county.Admin2}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

const StateList = () => {

/* below is the dropdown of states. this will be changed in the future to follow the same logic
as above. for right now, I just render 50 <option> elements, one for every US state*/

  return (
    <div>
      <label>state: </label>
      <select>
        <option value="default" selected>
          Select a state
        </option>
        <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
        {/*... 48 US states later ...*/
       <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

const UnitedStates = () => {
  return (
    <div className="dashboard">
      <div className="title">COVID-19 state and county visualizer</div>
      <div className="instructions">
        select a state and county to see charts and data about how COVID-19 has
        affected it from as early as January 2020 to present day.
      </div>
      <form
        onSubmit={() => {
          console.log("Working");
        }}
      >
        <StateList state={"enter state"} />
        <CountyList selectedState={"Alabama"} data={data} />
        <button type = "submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default UnitedStates;
```

However, I get this error thrown:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

  2 | import * as data from "./us_data/UScsvjson.json";
  3 | 
  4 | const CountyList = ({ selectedState, data }) => {
> 5 |   const countyListForState = JSON.parse(data)
  6 |     .filter((state) => selectedState === state.Province_State)
  7 |     .map((state) => state.Admin2);
  8 |
```

I assume that it stems from `JSON.parse`, but I am not sure how to fix it or how to read the `.json`  file otherwise.

The form logic might be messed up a little. For right now, I just want to be able to do the json parsing and build React components based on it.

Best and thanks so much

Comment: Are you using create react app?

Comment: @RobertTirta yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 modules implementation, how to load a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650399/es6-modules-implementation-how-to-load-a-json-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create-react-app includes `json-loader` module (previously), now in `webpack >= 2`, importing json is by [default](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/) available.

You should change your import to

`import data from "./us_data/UScsvjson.json";`

Then change your code to:

```
  const countyListForState = data
    .filter((state) => (selectedState === state.Province_State))
    .map((state) => state.Admin2);
```